# O que é programação orientada a aspectos?

Tags: engenharia-de-software

O que é programação orientada a aspectos? Ouvi a respeito numa conversa entre colegas esses dias. Ninguém soube me explicar bem e mais, disseram que era algo ruim.

Comment: `disseram que era algo ruim` **NUNCA** dê ouvidos a quem diz esse tipo de coisa sem dar uma explicação. Na idade média se dizia que tomates eram venenosos e ninguém os comia, mas nenhuma explicação era dada. Hoje temos o ketchup. Pense nisso ;)

Comment: @Renan deve ser por causa da tomatina que fica perto do caule e é tóxica. Ou quem sabe alguém tenha morrido na festa italiana de mesmo nome... /s :) Hortaliças à parte, concordo com seu comentário e o estendo às tais "boas práticas", que geralmente me soam como sinônimo de "nao sei bem ao certo o que eu tou fazendo, mas falaram que é bom assim". ;) Quanto à pergunta, +1.

Comment: @renan mas eu acho ketchup ruim...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Em resumo, a **Programação Orientada a Aspectos** ou *Aspect-Oriented Progrmming (AOP)* é um modelo de programação que possibilita a devida separação de responsabilidades, considerando funcionalidades que são essenciais para um grupo de objetos, mas não são de responsabilidade direta deles.

AOP é dita ortogonal porque geralmente envolve conceitos que independem da camada e não tem relação direta com os requisitos funcionais de um sistema.

Exemplos de aplicação de AOP são: geração de logs, controle de acesso e tratamentos excepcionais, transações.

Por exemplo, o método abaixo (em Java) contém lógica de negócios fictícia e vários tratamentos necessários em qualquer sistema corporativo: transação, segurança e logging. Procurei fazer o exemplo de modo a não ferir princípios e boas práticas de Orientação a Objetos.

Veja o método:

```java
//Inversão de Controle: dependências são recebidas por parâmetros
void processarOperacao(TransactionManager transacao, LogManager log, SecurityManager seguranca, OperacaoDAO dao, Operacao operacao) {
    try {

        //segurança
        if (seguranca.usuarioEstaLogado()) {
            log.info("Falha de segurança"); //log
            throw new AcessoNegadoException();
        }

        //transação
        transacao.begin();
        processamentoComplexoOperacao(operacao);
        dao.salvarOperacao(operacao);
        transacao.commit();
        log.info("Sucesso"); //log

    } catch (ErroNegocioException e) {
        //tratamento excepcional
        log.error("Falha", e); //log
        transacao.rollback(); 
    }
}
```

Os principais problemas com o código acima são:

- Ele se repetirá em todos os métodos do sistema.
- 99% do código trata de coisas ortogonais, isto é, a lógica de negócios está perdida no meio de várias questões técnicas.

Com a AOP podemos deixar o desenvolvedor se concentrar na lógica e delegar esses outros detalhes a um framework ou container com suporte à AOP.

Vamos ver agora um exemplo usando AOP:

```java
//dependências
@Inject OperacaoDao;

@UsuarioDeveEstarLogado //segurança
@Transactional //transação
void processarOperacao(Operacao operacao) {

    processamentoComplexoOperacao(operacao);
    dao.salvarOperacao(operacao);

}
```

Viu a diferença? Vou explicitar:

- **Dependências**: um framework injeta as dependências, então você não precisa de assinaturas ou construtores "sujos", isto é, com parâmetros estranhos à lógica.
- **Segurança**: frameworks podem interceptar métodos, então suponho que o seu framework vai interceptar a chamada a todos os métodos que possuem a anotação `@UsuarioDeveEstarLogado` e executar uma lógica que você escreve em um só lugar.
- **Transação**: o framework cria automaticamente a transação quando encontra a anotação `@Transactional`. Ele também controlar o `commit` ou `rollback` dependendo se o método lançou ou não uma exceção.
- **Logging**: o framework AOP pode automaticamente interceptar e logar todas as chamadas a métodos e as exceções que vierem a ocorrer.

Comment: Então no fim continua sendo orientada a objetos, mas com uma asbtração maior para com a lógica, deixando separado o código não pertinente ao mesmo?

Comment: @CaiqueC. Seria possível usar AOP com programação procedural, interceptando chamadas a funções e subrotinas e adicionando automaticamente transação, segurança, etc. A linguagem só precisa dar suporte a tecnicas de interceptação ou permitir o acesso a métodos por referência, por exemplo. Mas desconheço implementações de AOP que não sejam OO.

Comment: Então a programação orientada a aspectos no fim não seria uma paradigma? Estaria mais para um suporte a paradigma? Suporte á aspectos? rs

Comment: @CaiqueC. Só porque AOP trabalha com outros paradigmas não significa que não possa ser um paradigma. Python é uma linguagem que pode ser usada de forma estruturada somente com funções ou orientada a objetos. Uma coisa não exclui automaticamente a outra a não ser na cabeça das pessoas.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado :)

Answer (score 6):

Sobre ser ruim ou não, não existe, o que existe é se é adequado ou não a uma determinada situação e vai depender muito do desenvolvedor e do que está sendo desenvolvido. Particularmente, a POO sempre resolveu perfeitamente nossos problemas, então nunca tivemos a necessidade de desenvolver algo em um novo paradigma. **E como observação podemos utilizar POO em conjunto com POA.**

Segue alguns textos e suas referências que tenho aqui no meu histórico.

> Em ciência da computação, programação orientada a aspectos ou POA, é um paradigma de programação de computadores que permite aos desenvolvedores de software separar e organizar o código de acordo com a sua importância para a aplicação (separation of concerns). Todo o programa escrito no paradigma orientado a objetos possui código que é alheio a implementação do comportamento do objeto. Este código é todo aquele utilizado para implementar funcionalidades secundárias e que encontra-se espalhado por toda a aplicação (crosscutting concern). A POA permite que esse código seja encapsulado e modularizado.

**Referência:** http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_orientada_a_aspecto

> Sabe-se que no desenvolvimento de software existem propriedades que não se enquadram em 
>   componentes da decomposição funcional, tais como: tratamento de exceções, restrições de 
>   tempo real, distribuição e controle de concorrência. Elas normalmente estão espalhadas em 
>   diversos componentes do sistema afetando a performance ou a semântica da aplicação.
>
> Embora elas possam ser visualizadas e analisadas relativamente em separado, sua 
>   implementação utilizando linguagens orientadas a objeto ou estruturadas torna-se confusa e 
>   seu código encontra-se espalhado através do código da aplicação, dificultando a separação da 
>   funcionalidade básica do sistema dessas propriedades.
>
> A programação orientada a aspectos é uma abordagem que permite a separação dessas 
>   propriedades ortogonais dos componentes funcionais de uma forma natural e concisa, utilizando-se de mecanismos de abstração e de composição para a produção de código 
>   executável.

**Referência:** http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~rocha/college/src/aop.pdf

> Quando algo parecido com o registro de auditoria ocorrer, ou seja, um interesse atravessar a aplicação, inferindo muitos módulos, ou mais diretamente, este interesse “cortar” a aplicação, dizemos se tratar de um interesse entrecortante. O objetivo do desenvolvimento orientado a aspectos é encapsular esses interesses entrecortantes em módulos fisicamente separados do restante do código. Os módulos que abrigam esses interesses são chamados de aspectos. Se pensarmos em termos abstratos, a orientação a aspectos introduz uma terceira dimensão de decomposição. Lembrando o que vimos, a OO decompõe o sistema em objetos (dados) e métodos (funções). Por sua vez, os objetos e métodos podem ainda ser decompostos de acordo com um interesse comum. Ao se agrupar cada interesse em um módulo distinto, teremos a orientação a aspecto.

**Referência:** http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-a-orientacao-a-aspecto/27759