# Todo processador utiliza o mesmo conjunto de instruções?

Tags: assembly

Estava pesquisando sobre linguagem de máquina, mas tudo que achei na Internet é muito pouco e apenas teórico então queria saber se é possível eu criar um programa simples em linguagem de máquina.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O que vai achar por aí é teórico mesmo, prática é fazer, então faça, mas como vai fazer sem saber a teoria? A não ser que esteja se referenciando à prática como as receitas de bolo que alguns postam, isso não ensina ninguém. Talvez nessa área não se encontre mesmo este tipo de coisa, porque quem quer se embrenhar nela sabe que receitas não servem para nada.

Linguagem de máquina em si ninguém programa há várias décadas. As pessoas programam em Assembly que é um representação mais fácil para humanos, mas que tem uma relação direta com as instruções do processador. Esse código Assembly é montado para o código de máquina através de um *assembler* que é parecido com um [compilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101), mas muito mais simples.

Na verdade mesmo o Assembly hoje é usado em raros momentos, normalmente para fazer *bootstrap* de sistemas operacionais e outros ambientes, alguns pontos muito específicos em alguns *drivers*, a criação de *backends* de compiladores e algumas otimizações bem específicas. Hoje é raro o humano produzir código de máquina melhor que os compiladores fazem.

Cada família de processador (x86, ARM, MIPS, etc.) tem um conjunto de instruções específico. Mesmo processadores da mesma família variam. Gerações novas possuem novas instruções e eventualmente deixam de ter instruções que não fazem mais sentido, ainda que raro acontecer. Cada processador também tem seu jeito próprio de escrever código Assembly. Ainda que o Assembly seja uma abstração para humanos, há uma cultura própria em cima de cada processador.

Não só o Assembly deve ser específico para cada tipo de processador, mas também há diferenças entre as linguagens Assembly de fornecedores de montadores diferentes (para o [processador X86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language) é comum usar a sintaxe básica da [Intel ou da AT&T](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/DM18/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm) mais a [sintaxe do montador](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly)). O Assembly deve ser específico para o que se chama [*instruction set*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set).

Se já sabe programar em C escreva um código simples que só faça uma coisa e mande compilar para o Assembly. Ali você verá como o código em alto nível se transforma em baixo nível. Vá fazendo isso com diversas coisas que esteja curioso, vá experimentando. E aí comece fazer seus próprios códigos.

A [Wikipedia é um bom começo para os primeiros passos para entender do assunto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language). Conforme for aprendendo o básico, poderá partir para outros artigos lá mesmo ou nos indicados nas páginas. Depois terá melhores condições para fazer pesquisas e fazer perguntas específicas aqui.

Se quer aprender mesmo, procure livros. Coisas na internet ajudam, mas não substituem livros. Um [bom início e indicação de livro](http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/). [Esse outro é bem indicado](http://kipirvine.com/asm/). O [manual do processador](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html/) vai ajudar.

Estou passando tudo em inglês porque obviamente aprender Assembly sem saber inglês não combina.

Ah, programar em Assembly é **absurdamente** mais difícil que achar informações na internet sobre o assunto. Então aconselho reavaliar se está preparado para isso neste momento. Mas sua atitude é louvável, antes tivessem mais pessoas querendo aprender o todo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Assembly/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, queria apenas ter a experiencia de programar em linguagem de maquina e ver como funciona mais perto.
Li algumas coisas na wikipedia e sobre oque você disse sobre a receita de bolo, apenas queria ver como era um codigo de maquina mesmo que entendesse pouca coisa, Obrigado cara, foi difícil achar alguém que realmente "manjava" do assunto.