# Como usar várias linguagens em um único programa?

Tags: python, c++, assembly

Eu vi que o Google Chrome é feito em Python, C++ e Assembly e me veio a mente, como programar usando várias linguagens em um ÚNICO programa?

Comment: Cite a fonte onde diz isto.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la agora? Veja o [tour] para entender como funciona. Ajudaria muito indicar para todo mundo que a solução foi útil e satisfatória para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Comment: Vai de acordo com o contexto. Por exemplo, no Visual Studio dá para programar em assembly já arquivo-fonte em C++ diretamente para arquitetura x86 usando blocos __asm, já em x64 dá para fazer um arquivo-fonte em assembly com uma função e chamá-la no código-fonte C++, tudo seguindo uns padrões para funcionar. Também dá para fazer uma linguagem interpretada rodar um executável programado e compilado em outra, correto? Cada caso é um caso.

Answer (score 8):

C++, simplesmente falando, é uma linguagem que sempre gera um código binário executável para um processador depois de passar pelo [compilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101). Assembly faz o mesmo depois de passar pelo [montador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109886/101). Eles podem ser [*linkados*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) juntos sem problema algum. Tudo vira um único executável porque tudo é código executável, não faz diferença em que linguagem originalmente foi escrito o código fonte, o que importa aqui é o [código alvo que é específico para um processador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142289/101), é algo que o computador entende. O código fonte escrito em uma linguagem é algo para o programador entender.

Python é um pouco diferente. Geralmente roda de forma interpretada ou semi-interpretada (a grosso modo). Ou seja, precisa de uma máquina virtual que se comporta como se fosse um processador para executar as instruções da linguagem. Essa máquina virtual é um software como outro qualquer. A máquina virtual de Pyhton mais conhecida é escrita em C, que também gera um código binário, e pode ser *linkado* junto com o código gerado pelo C++ e pelo Assembly.

Já o código escrito em Pyhton mesmo, ou fica em um arquivo auxiliar, ou fica anexado ao executável como um recurso do arquivo executável ou mesmo um vetor de bytes. Ali pode conter ou o fonte em Python ou o *bytecode* dessa máquina virtual que será gerado do fonte em Pyhton por um compilador.

Essa técnica é conhecida por máquina virtual embarcada e pode ser feita com diversas outras linguagens como [Lua](https://www.lua.org/) e [Harbour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harbour_(software)), só para citar algumas.

Note que eu não sei se o Chrome é um único programa de fato. É possível fazer isso, mas nada garante que tenha sido feito. Antes de afirmar tenha certeza que isso é verdade, há muita informação desencontrada por aí. O que eu posso afirmar é que a base do código do Chrome é C++. Tem boa probabilidade de usar alguma mínima coisa em Assembly. Nada me indica que Python é realmente usado nele. Na verdade fui pesquisar e não só não encontrei nada sobre isto, como até alguém afirmando que não tem. Juntando minha observação com mais alguém afirmando, me faz acreditar que realmente isso é uma informação equivocada. Só não posso garantir.

Em alguns casos uma linguagem como Python é usada para *scripts* de desenvolvimento e testes, que é diferente do que está tratado aqui.

É possível usar Python em alguma implementação que gera executável e *linkar* junto com código C++ direto, mas isso não costuma acontecer. Nem sei o quanto a implementação que faz isso está sempre atualizada.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md)

Comment: Os programas em C/C++ não gera um código em Assembly, e a partir deste código Assembly que é gerado o código binário?

Comment: Aí depende do compilador. Em geral não produzem Assembly não, podem gerar algum outro código intermediário mais abstrato que Assembly. Mas nada impede que faça isto também. Só não vejo tanto sentido para o compilador fazer isto. Claro que um compilador muito simples pode delegar para um montador gerar o executável, aí sim ele geraria um fonte Assembly.

Answer (score 0):

No desenvolvimento de um sistema você utiliza várias linguagens de programação (C#, JavaScript, JQuery). Cada uma, conforme explicado na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/134600/51124) do Maniero, tem sua "especialidade".

A título de curiosidade, segundo esse [fórum](https://www.quora.com/What-programming-languages-are-web-browsers-like-Google-Chrome-Opera-and-Mozilla-Firefox-written-in), os navegadores foram desenvolvidos:

#### Firefox

- Renderização: Gecko, C++
- JavaScript engine: SpiderMonkey, C
- Interface de usuário: Mostly XUL (a custom XML dialect), CSS, and JavaScript, with some C++.

#### Chrome

- Renderização: WebCore, C++
- JavaScript engine: V8, C++
- Interface de usuário: Principalmente C, embora a porta mac usa Objective-C, e algumas características em HTML, CSS e JavaScript.

#### Safari

- Renderização: WebCore, C++ (compartilhado com Chrome)
- JavaScript engine: JavaScriptCore, C++
- Interface de usuário: provavelmente Objective-C com HTML

#### Internet Explorer

- Todo em C++

#### Opera

- Opera mudou para Webkit e V8, mas a renderização foi escrita em C++

Answer (score 0):

Complementando as respostas anteriores.

Isso acontece porque na programação existem alguns "protocolos" e padrões na hora de compartilhar dados, conhecido como API (*Application Programming Interface"*), que permite a troca de informações entre aplicações independente de sua linguagem de programação.

Um exemplo:

Você tem um buscador de de filmes personalizado com base no que seria mais recomendado para o seu usuário.

No *frontend* você tem o JavaScript dando *handle* nos inputs e usando o protocolo HTTP para enviar a *query* do input de busca no formato JSON pro *backend*.

No *backend*, uma API em C# pega essa *query* em JSON, transforma em uma String e compartilha com um script Python rodando no mesmo banco, esse script, por sua vez, usa Inteligência Artificial pra descobrir qual a melhor recomendação de filme pra você com base na sua *query* e retorna uma resposta em JSON com uma lista de filmes pro C#.

O C#, por sua vez, retorna esse JSON pro *frontend*.