# Tornar um código executável

Tags: python-3.x

É possível tornar um código executável sem baixar nada e sendo feito numa IDE online?

Comment: Tem uma outra forma https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134596/101. IDE online é só pra fazer algo rapidinho, mostra para alguém e boa.

Comment: Talvez 'chmod +x nomedoarquivo.py' ajude.

Comment: @LuigiMatheus Poderia mostrar o passo a passo?

Comment: Tem acesso ao CLI? Só digitar esse comando e trocar o "nomedoarquivo" pelo nome do arquivo. Qual IDE Online está usando?