# Usar mais de uma linguagem no mesmo projeto?

Tags: python, vb.net

estou participando de um projeto que vou precisar de duas partes:

```
1) Extração de dados da internet
2) Criação da Interface Gráfica para Desktop
```

Para a 1ª, pensei em usar Python por ler que ele é a melhor linguagem para extração de dados e para a 2ª, usar VB.NET. Queria saber se isso é desaconselhável em programação por talvez gerar alguma possível incompatibilidade entre as duas linguagens ou por outro motivo.

Answer (score 2):

Já respondi isso em [Como usar várias linguagens em um único programa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134596/101). Mas falando em específico ao que foi perguntando, não tem problema usar mais de uma linguagem em uma solução, você faz uma aplicação em uma e outra nem fica sabendo em que linguagem foi feita outra parte. Isto é bom? Geralmente não, existem bem poucos casos que isso é vantajoso, quase sempre a pessoa opta por fazer isso por não dominar o que está fazendo e por si só pode ser um problema ou porque é por razões políticas de uma organização e não por razões técnicas. Mas tudo funciona se fizer certo, só precisa trocar dados de forma consistente.

Se quer juntar duas linguagens na mesma aplicação, depende das linguagens usadas. Se forem *scripts* eu nem chamaria de aplicação e dá para mais ou menos misturar, porque no fundo você passa ter uma solução de *scripts* e não uma aplicação única. Se for gerar um executável, precisa que todas sejam compatíveis em fazer isto e poder se comunicar, falo isto nas outras respostas lá.

Se for usar o VB.NET usará o .NET ([Core, por favor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101)) poderá usar outras linguagens porque a plataforma foi feita para isto, mas não qualquer uma. Funciona direitinho, mas provavelmente é gambiarra em grande parte das situações, não quer dizer que será super simples e não tenha trabalho para lidar com isso. Mas o VB.NET já trabalha com mais que uma linguagem, tudo que ele usa internamente é feito em C#.

Eu vejo como problema maior começar algo novo porque gosta mais de uma linguagem por causa da sintaxe, uma linguagem que claramente está com suporte secundário do fornecedor e a comunidade praticamente abandonou de vez. Então está olhando para o problema errado.

Python pode ser usado junto com .NET, mas quase sempre faz pouco sentido. Se for usado fora da plataforma então é só uma solução com duas aplicações isoladas e cai no que eu falei antes. Novamente, não sei se isso é necessário se vai fazer algo do zero, quase sempre esse tipo de coisa é quando há legado ou algo pronto.

O que descreveu parece um caso que o VB.NET dá conta de tudo muito bem. Por outro lado, o Python também dá conta de tudo quase tão quanto o VB.NET (um pouco menos por algumas razões, depende dos detalhes do que precisa).

Não vai nessa do que lê por aí. Python não tem absolutamente nada melhor para extração de dados, isto é só gente fazendo marketing da sua tecnologia favorita. Se você nem sabe porque está adotando, só seguindo o que outras pessoas estão dizendo então toda decisão está errada. Não faça baseado em suposições expostas por pessoas aleatórias na internet que você não sabe quais as motivações dela de dizer aquilo, porque ela acha aquilo, e geralmente ela não dá uma avaliação provando aquilo que ela está afirmando, ou seja, mostra como a linguagem faz melhor que outras, mostrando como se faz nas duas. Mesmo que ela mostre em geral a pessoa é tendencioso, de propósito ou não, afinal ela conhece bem uma das linguagens e não a outra. E muitas vezes ela demonstra um pequeno detalhe melhor, ignora todos os outros pior, ou que dá para fazer na outra de um jeito diferente e melhor, e quando as vezes parece melhor pode ser só gosto e no fundo não faz diferença real. Nem falei que normalmente a pessoa que conhece bem uma não conhece bem a outra, mesmo que tenha algo melhor em uma pode ser que não seja bem explorada pela pessoa que não conhece muito bem aquela tecnologia. Um dos maiores motivos para usar duas linguagens é que tem duas equipes com *skills* em cada uma delas, e precisa separar o projeto entre as duas. Ou seja, é gambiarra tecnológica para favorecer um melhor gerenciamento de projeto.

Python é bem mais lenta que VB.NET, os fontes são mais expostos que VB.NET, o *deploy* é mais complicado em quase todas as situações, só para citar algumas questões.

Usar mais de uma linguagem precisa compensar muito, precisa provar antes que será melhor antes de tomar a decisão, não pode ser achismo, porque complica mais o desenvolvimento. Me parece que está decidindo usar mais que uma pelo motivo errado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

Sim é possível usar mais de uma linguagem em algum software, a questão mais importante é se elas precisam interagir entre si.

Por exemplo, os dados extraídos precisam ser exibidos no *desktop*. Nesse caso, precisa de uma interface comum que as duas partes entendam, pode ser um banco de dados por exemplo, onde uma parte escreva e a outra possa ler os dados, funcionando perfeitamente para quaisquer linguagens que você escolha.

Não vou falar sobre as linguagens em sim porque seria baseada em minha opinião, mas quanto ao `VB.NET`, se quer usar a plataforma `.NET`, sugiro usar `C#`, que é muito mais popular e difundida, não é opinião, são fatos.  Um exemplo é a pesquisa do próprio Stack Oerflow, que você pode ler aqui: [Stack Overflow Survey 2019](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted)

Comment: Eu sei que C# é mais popular, mas prefiro usar vb.net, gosto mais

Comment: Tranquilo, precisamos usar o que funciona melhor pra nós, só inclui a informação para ajudar na sua escolha :)

Answer (score -1):

De forma pragmática.
Utilize Python para a extração de dados, (BS, scrapy. requestes.) apos isso armazene os dados em um banco de dados e depois basta acessar os dados com outra linguagem.

O interessante disso é que depois pode-se utilizar qualquer outra linguagem para alimentar o banco de dados.