# O que é analise léxica?

Tags: terminologia, parser, analise-léxica

Eu estava dando uma olhada no código-fonte de uma library conhecida do php, chamada `Twig` (trata-se de um template engine, com sintaxe própria), e me deparei com classes, interfaces e métodos, como `Lexical`, `Lex` e `LexInterface`.

Dei uma pesquisada e percebi que se tratava do termo *análise léxica*.

Apesar de ter entendido algumas coisas, fiquei confuso em outras.

Por exemplo, estou acostumado a ver o termo `Parser` ou `Parsing`, quando se trata em transformação de um determinado dado em outro dado.

- O que seria a Análise Léxica?
- Análise Léxica e Parsing/Parser se trata das mesmas coisas, ou na verdade são coisas diferentes?

Desculpem se estou confuso na pergunta, mas creio que a comunidade me ajudará com uma boa e esclarecedora resposta.

Comment: Talvez responda http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/104818/91, mais ou menos no meio da resposta tem uma explicação sobre análise léxica.

Comment: @rray já é um bom caminho. Eu não saberia pesquisar (um termo específico) para descobrir como chegar nessa resposta.

Comment: Você escuta bastante esse termo em autômatos.

Comment: Você não consegue "proteger" sua pergunta de votos contras, a proteção apenas evita que novos usuários respondam ela, não faz muito sentido proteger sua pergunta no momento ;-)

Comment: Eu sei @Math. Eu confesso que protejo algumas só para poder usar a funcionalidade, rsrsrsrs.

Comment: @WallacedeSouza: o link informado no comentário do rray tem uma resposta **excelente** para essa pergunta. Você espera uma resposta mais "prática"? Um exemplo simples de construção de um compilador? (eu respondi uma pergunta sobre o assunto aqui: [Parser identificando tokens de forma errada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113824/parser-identificando-tokens-de-forma-errada-flex-e-bison) ). Enfim, qual a sua expectativa para uma boa resposta?

Comment: @Gomiero na época que eu coloquei ela na recompensa não tinha tantos detalhes assim. Só vou dar a recompensa quando estiver faltando algum tempo. Assim, as respostas ficam visíveis para outras pessoas verem e também formarem uma opnião.

Comment: @WallacedeSouza: Ok! Obrigado :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Definição

Análise léxica é o processo realizado sobre um texto, digamos um programa de computador ou então uma linguagem de marcação como HTML, que divide este em `lexemes` e os converte para uma sequência de `tokens`, os quais são usados para alimentar um [`parser`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C3%A1lise_sint%C3%A1tica_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)). Um programa que realiza análise léxica é geralmente chamado de `lexer`, `scanner` ou `tokenizer`.

### tokens / lexemes

*Lexemes* são unidades sintáticas relevantes do contexto do lexer, por exemplo para um lexer voltado a uma certa linguagem de programação alguns lexemes poderiam ser: 1, "olá", for, ==, variableName, function.

Um *token* é uma estrutura que categoriza um lexeme, ele contêm um nome abstrato que representa o grupo do lexeme e um possível valor deste caso o grupo não seja único. Exemplo de alguns tokens (o token é representado no formato < token, valor-opcional> e "#" representa início de comentários):

```
< digit, 1 > # qualquer valor numérico
< literal, "olá" > # valores contidos entre aspas duplas
< for > # os caracteres f,o,r
< comparison, == > # os símbolos <, >, <=, >=, == e !=
< id, variableName > # sequência de letras que representa uma variável
< function > # as letras f,u,n,c,t,i,o,n
```

### diferença entre parsing

Lexers e parsers estão intimamente ligados contudo são conceitos distintos. O lexer é especializado em extrair as porções relevantes do texto e transformá-las em estruturas com "significado", no caso os tokens. Já o parser tem a função de analisar a estrutura sintática de um texto, por exemplo dizer se em uma determinada linguagem de programação a expressão `"olá" 1 == "outroliteral"` é sintaticamente válida ou inválida. A ligação entre ambos é a de que as estruturas produzidas pelo lexer são o que parser usa como fonte para realizar o parsing, ou seja, o parser trabalha com tokens. Isso não é obrigatório, nada te impede de construir um parser que faça a análise sintática em cima de texto puro, contudo a separação das duas tarefas traz algumas vantagens:

1. Simplificação do design. Um parser que também realize o trabalho de um lexer é significantemente mais complexo.
2. Otimização. Separando as duas tarefas (lexing e parsing) você tem mais liberdade para aplicar ténicas de otimização específicas para cada tarefa.

### um lexer na prática

A teoria é essencial, contudo nada melhor que código real para ajudar na compreensão. Aqui eu mostro um lexer feito a mão em javascript que lida com um subconjunto de CSS, mais especificamente ele lida com este exemplo:

```
h1 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 30px;
}

body {
    background-color: yellow;
}

div {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

O código pode ser executado e irá mostrar a lista de tokens gerados após processar nosso CSS alvo:

```js
// nosso CSS
var css = "h1 { \n\
 color: red; \n\
 font-size: 30px; \n\
} \n\
 \n\
body { \n\
 background-color: yellow; \n\
} \n\
 \n\
div { \n\
 margin: 10px; \n\
 padding: 10px; \n\
} \n\
";

/**
* Lista que define nossos tokens e as respectivas expressões regulares que os encontram no texto.
*/
var TOKENS = [
 {name: 'EMPTY', regex: /^(\s+)/ },
 {name: 'RULE_SET_START', regex: /^({)/ },
 {name: 'RULE_SET_END', regex: /^(})/ },
 {name: 'RULE_DEFINITION', regex: /^(:)/ },
 {name: 'RULE_END', regex: /^(;)/ },
 {name: 'SELECTOR', regex: /^([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*)(?=\s*{)/ },
 {name: 'RULE', regex: /^([a-z][-a-z]+)(?=\s*:)/ },
 {name: 'RULE_VALUE', regex: /^(\w+)(?=\s*(;|}))/ }
];


var text = css;
var outputTokenList = [];
while(text !== '') { // enquanto existir texto a ser consumido

 var hasMatch = false;
 
 /**
    * Iteramos sobre toda a lista de TOKENS até encontrarmos algum cujo padrão bata com o início do nosso texto.
    * Quando ocorre um "match" nós adicionamos o lexeme com seu respectivo token na lista de tokens de saída do lexer.
    * Caso nenhum padrão bata com o texto uma exceção é lançada imprimindo a linha que contêm o erro.
  *
  */
 for (var i=0; i<TOKENS.length; i++) {
  var obj = TOKENS[i];
  var tokenName = obj.name;
  var tokenRegex = obj.regex;
  
  var matched = text.match(tokenRegex);
  if (!matched) {
   continue;
  }
  
  hasMatch = true;
  var lexeme = matched[1];
  
  // removemos do texto o lexeme encontrado
  // para que outro possa ser considerados
  // na próxima iteração
  text = text.substring(lexeme.length);

  if (tokenName in {'SELECTOR': 1, 'RULE': 1, 'RULE_VALUE': 1}) {
   // adicionamos tanto o nome do token quanto o lexeme
   outputTokenList.push([tokenName, lexeme]);
  }
  else if (tokenName in {'EMPTY': 1}) {
   // discard, não nos importamos com espaços e quebras de linha.
  }
  else {
   // nestes casos o relacionamento entre o nome do token
   // e o lexeme é 1<->1 então não precisamos adicionar o lexeme.
   outputTokenList.push([tokenName]);   
  }
  
  break;
 };

 if (!hasMatch) {
  throw 'Invalid pattern at:\n' + (text.substring(0, text.indexOf('\n')));
  break;
 }
}

outputTokenList.forEach(function(token) {
 document.write('< ' + token[0]);
    if (token.length > 1) {
     document.write(' , ' + token[1]);
    }
 document.write(' ><br>');
});
```

Não vou entrar em explicações sobre as implementações de lexers pois este é um assunto extenso e não diretamente relacionado a pergunta, então note que esta é apenas uma ilustração do possível funcionamento de um lexer, lê um texto alvo e gera tokens como saída, o código não é nem eficiente nem robusto.

Comment: Gostei! (+1) e vou roubar o teu exemplo na minha resposta :)

Answer (score 13):

> O que seria a Análise Léxica?

É a análise de linhas de caracteres para se criar símbolos que facilitem a compreensão do que está escrito ali.

> Análise Léxica e Parsing/Parser se trata das mesmas coisas, ou na verdade são coisas diferentes?

São complementares.

A primeira etapa é a geração de símbolos (tokens), chamada de análise léxica, pelo qual o fluxo de caracteres de entrada é dividido em símbolos significativos definidos por uma gramática de expressões regulares.

A segunda etapa é a análise sintática, que é a verificação de que os tokens formam uma expressão permitida.

A fase final é a análise semântica, que elabora as implicações da expressão validada e toma a ação apropriada.

Comment: "Primeira etapa, segunda etapa, fase final" etapas/fases do que? imagino que sejam o front end de um compilador, contudo faltou especificar isto no texto.

Comment: Etapas de um parser (analisador? desconheço uma boa tradução). Pode realmente ser de um compilador, já que ele precisa fazer isso, mas pode ser de um parser que esteja analisando uma comunicação XML ou JSON, por exemplo.

Answer (score 10):

Análise léxica e sintática (*parsing*) são de fato coisas bem parecidas, tendo em vista que os algoritmos que trabalham nessas duas frentes operam de forma similar: a entrada processada por ambos é similar e os resultados que apresentam também.

Conforme mencionaram nos comentários da pergunta, de fato se ouve muito essa expressão quando se estuda autômatos justamente porque analisadores léxicos lidam apenas com [linguagens regulares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). Na prática, um analisador léxico atua como um reconhecedor de tokens. Isto é, dada a gramática de uma linguagem regular qualquer, um analisador léxico é capaz de determinar se dada sequência de caracteres faz parte dessa linguagem ou não. Daí vem as famosas expressões regulares.

Diferentemente, parsers atuam com um nível mais complexo de linguagens pois lidam com [linguagens livres de contexto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language). Também na prática, parsers costumam processar uma sequência de tokens (geralmente reconhecidos por lexers) e determinam se tais tokens satisfazem as estruturas definidas na gramática dessa linguagem.

Portanto, a análise léxica consiste em validar tokens levando em consideração as regras de formação de uma linguagem regular, se essa linguagem não é mais regular, então trata-se de um parser. No caso do Twig, por se tratar de uma engine de templates, acredito que a análise léxica ocorra no reconhecimento dos marcadores especiais como `{{`, `else`, `{%` etc.

---

Estou **atualizando** minha resposta por acreditar que ela não foi ampla o suficiente e também por achar que as outras respostas apresentadas ou foram genéricas demais ou atrelaram muito lexers a parsers.

Primeiro as semelhanças fundamentais entre lexers e parsers:

1. Ambos tem como entrada símbolos de algum alfabeto. Geralmente os símbolos de um lexer são caracteres ASCII ou Unicode enquanto que parsers processam tokens (símbolos terminais da gramática que estão validando).
2. Eles analisam esses símbolos associando-os a uma gramática pra reconhecê-los como membros de uma linguagem. Conforme expliquei acima, lexers validam apenas **linguagens regulares** enquanto que parsers operam em **linguagens livres de contexto**. Níveis 3 e 2 na [hierarquia de Chomsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#The_hierarchy), respectivamente.
3. Ambos produzem como saída sentenças da linguagem que estão avaliando. Lexers distinguem **tokens** de uma sequência de caracteres dada como entrada, enquanto que parsers geram **árvores sintáticas**.

Com relação ao último ponto, ainda que ambos sejam complementares na grande maioria dos casos, isso não significa que um parser sempre haverá de receber sua entrada tokenizada de um lexer. Sendo um parser capaz de gerar múltiplas sentenças de uma linguagem L1 qualquer, podemos obter uma linguagem L2 cujos tokens sejam sentenças de L1. Sendo assim, parsers também podem ser tokenizadores de outros parsers.

Em processamento de linguagem natural, parsers obtém sua entrada tokenizada a partir de uma série de etapas que podem envolver edição manual, análise estatística e machine learning.

Portanto, a diferença fundamental entre ambos é como eu já expliquei acima: o nível da linguagem em que operam e consequentemente a complexidade necessária para operar sob este nível. Enquanto que pra linguagens regulares autômatos de estado finito são suficientes, linguagens livres de contexto requerem mecanismos mais complexos como [autômatos de pilha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) e toda a enorme variação de parsers existentes (bottom-up, top-down, tabulares etc).

Comment: Tem afirmações erradas aí Roney: " a análise léxica consiste em validar tokens", a análise léxica _produz_ tokens e não valida eles, pois tokens não existem antes de o lexer os gerar, a validação ocorre sobre os _lexemes_.

Comment: @BrunoRB lexers não são mecanismos geradores, portanto não produzem tokens. Eles validam a entrada como tokens ou não. Você pode entender como produção por ainda estar amarrado ao seu emprego no front-end de um compilador, mas são em suma reconhecedores de sua entrada tendo em vista visto uma gramática regular referencial. Distinguir numa string de entrada quais são os tokens da linguagem referência não implica que tais tokens são produzidos. Deixei explícito na resposta que tokens são nada mais que os símbolos atômicos de uma LR, portanto não há porque produzir o que já existe.

Comment: `... the main task of the lexical analyzer is to
read the input characters of the source program, group them into lexemes, and
produce as output a sequence of tokens for each lexeme in the source program` Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools.

Comment: @BrunoRB sim cara, é uma definição entre tantas. A distinção entre tokens e lexemas são terminologias criadas pra melhor apresentar os conceitos interessantes à sua aplicação em compiladores. Eu utilizo uma definição distinta em que o termo token é empregado como "constituinte atômico de uma linguagem". Contanto que as ideias apresentadas sejam coerentes com a definição, não há porque debater. Eu poderia chamá-los de bolinha, se fosse interessante. Acredito que fui coerente com a definição que apresentei e por isso não vejo sentido em extender esse não diálogo.

Comment: @BrunoRB com teus comentários notei uma possível contradição na minha resposta e a editei pra que fique mais explícito o meu entendimento do assunto. Obrigado.

Answer (score 8):

Um interpretador/compilador não entende "texto grosso" diretamente, ele precisa dos dados bem organizados e definidos.

Por exemplo, vamos supor que nosso interpretador precise interpretar essa simples soma:

```
42 + 42
```

Como resolvemos isso? É aí que entra o papel do analisador léxico.

O programador que criou nosso interpretador imaginário definiu que um número é o conjunto de 1 dígito seguido de outros dígitos e que soma é simplesmente o símbolo '+'.

```
[0-9]+ returns NUMBER;
"+"    returns PLUS;
" "    ;
```

E agora? Bom, vamos analisar o que acontece quando ele analisa a entrada, sendo o ponto final o caractere que ele está analisando:

**1)** **.** 42 (Nosso analisador contém o número 4 no buffer, ele sabe que pela definição, um número é 1 dígito seguido de mais dígitos.)

**2)** 4 **.** 2 (Até agora, ele possui 4 como número e continua, armazenando 2 no buffer.)

**3)** 42 **.** (É o fim do número, nosso interpretador retorna NUMBER. Encontramos um espaço em branco, que pela definição, não retorna nada.)

Por enquanto, sabemos isso:

```
<NUMBER, 42> . + 42
```

O analisador está sobre o '+', ele sabe que pela definição é um PLUS:

```
<NUMBER, 42> <PLUS, '+'> . 42
```

E é o mesmo processo sobre o 42:

```
<NUMBER, 42> <PLUS, '+'> <NUMBER, 42>
```

A análise foi concluída, e agora? Nosso interpretador pode interpretar esses dados de forma consistente. Vamos supor que nosso interpretador use uma gramática bem simples e restritiva para somas:

```
sum -> NUMBER PLUS NUMBER
```

Ele pode utilizar os tokens de saída do analisador léxico e se focar somente no parsing. Como a saída consiste de NUMBER PLUS NUMBER, se enquadra como uma soma válida.

Answer (score 7):

As respostas apresentadas são muito boas, e já abordaram toda a parte técnica do assunto. Portanto, apenas complementando a informação, segue uma explicação focada apenas na etimologia das palavras.

---

## Análise Léxica

Refere-se ao **vocabulário da linguagem (palavras)**. De uma forma simples, é uma análise de dicionário e verifica a existência dos termos/vocábulos dentro da linguagem.
Por exemplo "carnaval", "ovo", "bola" fazem parte do léxico da língua portuguesa. Já as palavras "party", "egg", "ball" fazem parte do léxico da língua inglesa. A *análise léxica* não se preocupa com ordem ou sentido dos termos, mas somente com os termos em si.

> Você pode ver um exemplo técnico [aqui](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Constru%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_compiladores/An%C3%A1lise_l%C3%A9xica).

## Análise Sintática

Refere-se as **regras gramaticais da linguagem**, ou seja, trata-se de como podemos organizar os termos da linguagem para criar um sentido. Pode encarar como a forma em que um comando deve ser estruturado para executar uma ação, ou as regras para a formação de uma frase.

> Exemplo técnico [aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C3%A1lise_sint%C3%A1tica_%28computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29).

## Análise Semântica

Aqui estamos falando do **sentido/significado empregado na frase/comando**. Por exemplo, podemos utilizar a frase `Me inclui fora dessa`, onde as palavras e a sintaxe estão corretas mas semanticamente não.

> Exemplo técnico [aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C3%A1lise_sem%C3%A2ntica).

---

Essas definições fazem parte da linguística como um todo e são utilizadas como uma forma de organizar e facilitar o entendimento de como um código/processo se propõe a trabalhar.

Escolhi não utilizar uma abordagem técnica e passar exemplos da língua portuguesa, pois eles são igualmente válidos quando você pensa nas linguagens de programação e tornam o entendimento dos termos mais simples.

Comment: (+1) sujestão: junta a pragmática!

Answer (score 6):

Já se disse tudo; no entanto eu gosto de processadores de linguagens, e não resisto a pôr aqui um exemplo neste caso Lex+Yacc.

Enunciado: dado uma CSS (simplificada, vou tomar como exemplo o caso apresentado por @BrunoRP) calcular quantas propriedades tem cada tag.

### Gramática tradutora: gramática + ações semânticas

Analisador sintatico=parser  (yacc)

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%union {char *s; int i;}
%token <s> ID STR MEA
%type  <i> props

%%
css  :                                      // bloco*
     | css bloco
     ;
bloco: ID '{' props '}'  { printf("%s - %d\n",$1,$3);}
     ;
props:                   { $$ = 0    ;}     // prop*
     | props prop        { $$ = $1+1 ;}     // contar as prop
     ;
prop : ID ':' v ';'      ;                  // propriedade
v    : ID | STR | MEA    ;                  // valor
%%
#include "lex.yy.c"

yyerror(char *s){fprintf(stderr,"ERRO (linha %d):'%s'\n-%s",yylineno, yytext,s);}

int main() { yyparse(); return 0; }
```

### Analidasor léxico (flex)

```
%option yylineno
%option noyywrap

%%
[ \n\t]+              {  } // ignorar espaços
#.*                   {  } // ignorar comentários

[{}:;]                { return yytext[0];} // caracteres especiais

[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]* { yylval.s=strdup(yytext);  return ID;  }
\"[^\"]*\"            { yylval.s=strdup(yytext);  return STR; }
[0-9]+(px|pt|mm)      { yylval.s=strdup(yytext);  return MEA; }

.  {fprintf(stderr,"%d: Erro - invalid character '%c'\n",yylineno,yytext[0]);}

%%
```

O que é a análise léxica:

1. saltar os espaços e comentários
2. retornar os códigos das palavras reservadas e carateres especias
3. agrupar os caracter que formam os ID, etc; retornar o seu código e valor
4. tratar dos erros léxicos

Compilando e testando:

```
$ flex proc.l
$ yacc proc.y
$ cc -o proc y.tab.c
$ proc < ex.css      ##ex.css é o exemplo de css do @BrunoRP

h1 - 2
body - 1
div - 2
```