# Parser identificando tokens de forma errada (Flex e Bison)

Tags: c, compiladores, token

Estou implementando um compilador com base na linguagem Tiger proposta pelo livro do Andrew Appel "Modern Compiler Implementation in C". 
Link: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/c/project.html

Estou utilizando os arquivos disponiveis no site do livro, porém ao executar o parser, os tokens informados na mensagem de erro são errados. Por exemplo, usando esse arquivo de entrada:

```
    let 
        type rectype = {name:string, id:int}

        var a:= rectype nil
    in
        a
    end
```

Eu recebo o seguinte erro:

```
testes/teste1:1.1: syntax error, unexpected MAIOR_IGUAL
Parsing failed
```

No entanto o token que ele deveria mostrar seria o "LET". Já fiz o teste com o lexer e os tokens mostrados por ele são corretos:

```
Token:        LET | Posicao:    1 | Valor:    -
Token:       TYPE | Posicao:    6 | Valor:    -
Token:         ID | Posicao:   11 | Valor: rectype 
Token:      IGUAL | Posicao:   19 | Valor:    -
Token:     ACHAVE | Posicao:   21 | Valor:    -
Token:         ID | Posicao:   22 | Valor: name
....
```

Cheguei a conclusão de que estou fazendo alguma coisa na compilação, ou então, meu arquivo tiger.grm (o arquivo de entrada do bison) tem algo errado, porém, não sei o que. Eu compilo o lexer e uso o arquivo "lex.yy.c" que é gerado para compilar com o parser depois. 
Compilação do lexer:

```
lextest: driver.o lex.yy.o errormsg.o util.o
    cc -g -o lextest driver.o lex.yy.o errormsg.o util.o

driver.o: driver.c tokens.h errormsg.h util.h
    cc -g -c driver.c

errormsg.o: errormsg.c errormsg.h util.h
    cc -g -c errormsg.c

lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c tokens.h errormsg.h util.h
    cc -g -c lex.yy.c

lex.yy.c: tiger.l
    lex tiger.l

util.o: util.c util.h
    cc -g -c util.c

clean: 
    rm -f a.out util.o driver.o lex.yy.o lex.yy.c errormsg.o
```

Compilação do parser (usando o lex.yy.c gerado anteriomente):

```
a.out: parsetest.o y.tab.o lex.yy.o errormsg.o util.o
cc -g parsetest.o y.tab.o lex.yy.o errormsg.o util.o

parsetest.o: parsetest.c errormsg.h util.h
    cc -g -c parsetest.c

y.tab.o: y.tab.c
    cc -g -c y.tab.c

y.tab.c: tiger.grm
    yacc -dv tiger.grm

y.tab.h: y.tab.c
    echo "y.tab.h was created at the same time as y.tab.c"

errormsg.o: errormsg.c errormsg.h util.h
    cc -g -c errormsg.c

lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c y.tab.h errormsg.h util.h
    cc -g -c lex.yy.c

#lex.yy.c: tiger.lex
#   lex tiger.lex

util.o: util.c util.h
    cc -g -c util.c

clean: 
    rm -f a.out util.o parsetest.o lex.yy.o errormsg.o y.tab.c y.tab.h y.tab.o
```

O lexer e parser são (respectivamente):

```
%{
#include <string.h>
#include "util.h"
#include "tokens.h"
#include "errormsg.h"

int charPos=1;

int yywrap(void){
    charPos=1;
    return 1;
}

void adjust(void){
    EM_tokPos=charPos;
    charPos+=yyleng;
}

%}

digit       [0-9]
letter      [a-zA-Z]
integer     {digit}+
identifier  {letter}("_"|{letter}|{digit})*
%x C_COMMENT

%%

{integer}       {adjust(); yylval.ival = atoi(yytext);   return INT;}

"/*"                        {BEGIN(C_COMMENT);}
<C_COMMENT>"*/"             {BEGIN(INITIAL);}
<C_COMMENT>.                { }

<INITIAL>"to"                       {adjust(); return TO;}
<INITIAL>"break"                        {adjust(); return BREAK;}
<INITIAL>"let"                      {adjust(); return LET;}
<INITIAL>"in"                       {adjust(); return IN;}
<INITIAL>"end"                      {adjust(); return END;}
<INITIAL>"function"                     {adjust(); return FUNCTION;}
<INITIAL>"var"                      {adjust(); return VAR;}
<INITIAL>"type"                         {adjust(); return TYPE;}
<INITIAL>"array"                    {adjust(); return ARRAY;}
<INITIAL>"if"                       {adjust(); return IF;}
<INITIAL>"then"                         {adjust(); return THEN;}
<INITIAL>"else"                         {adjust(); return ELSE;}
<INITIAL>"do"                       {adjust(); return DO;}
<INITIAL>"of"                       {adjust(); return OF;}
<INITIAL>"nil"                      {adjust(); return NIL;}
<INITIAL>"string"                   {adjust(); return STRING;}

<INITIAL>","                        {adjust(); return VIRGULA;}
<INITIAL>":"                        {adjust(); return DOIS_PONTOS;}
<INITIAL>";"                        {adjust(); return PTO_VIRGULA;}
<INITIAL>"("                        {adjust(); return APARENT;}
<INITIAL>")"                        {adjust(); return FPARENT;}
<INITIAL>"["                            {adjust(); return ACOLCH;}
<INITIAL>"]"                        {adjust(); return FCOLCH;}
<INITIAL>"{"                            {adjust(); return ACHAVE;}
<INITIAL>"}"                        {adjust(); return FCHAVE;}
<INITIAL>"."                        {adjust(); return PONTO;}
<INITIAL>"+"                        {adjust(); return SOMA;}
<INITIAL>"-"                        {adjust(); return SUB;}
<INITIAL>"*"                        {adjust(); return MUL;}
<INITIAL>"/"                        {adjust(); return DIV;}
<INITIAL>"="                        {adjust(); return IGUAL;}
<INITIAL>"<>"                       {adjust(); return DIF;}
<INITIAL>"<"                        {adjust(); return MENOR;}
<INITIAL>"<="                       {adjust(); return MENOR_IGUAL;}
<INITIAL>">"                        {adjust(); return MAIOR;}
<INITIAL>">="                       {adjust(); return MAIOR_IGUAL;}
<INITIAL>"&"                        {adjust(); return AND;}
<INITIAL>"|"                        {adjust(); return OR;}
<INITIAL>":="                       {adjust(); return ATRIBUICAO;}

<INITIAL>{identifier}               {adjust(); yylval.sval = String(yytext); return ID;}
<INITIAL>[0-9][a-z]*                    {adjust(); EM_error(EM_tokPos, "Erro: token ilegal.");}

<INITIAL>[ \t]+                     {adjust(); continue;}
<INITIAL>\n                         {adjust(); EM_newline();}
<INITIAL>[a-z]"."                       {adjust(); EM_error(EM_tokPos, "Erro: token ilegal.");}
<INITIAL>.                          {adjust(); EM_error(EM_tokPos, "Unknown character");}

%%
```

Desconsiderem a gramática, não tenho como testar ela com esse erro, então provavelmente deve estar toda errada. Já testei com uma bem simples e vi que não influencia nenhuma no erro.

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "util.h"
#include "errormsg.h"

int yylex(void); /* function prototype */

void yyerror(char *s){
    EM_error(EM_tokPos, "%s", s);
}

%}

%union {
    int pos;
    int ival;
    string sval;
}

%token <sval> ID STRING
%token <ival> INT

%error-verbose

%token  TO BREAK LET IN END FUNCTION VAR
%token  TYPE ARRAY IF THEN ELSE DO OF NIL
%token  VIRGULA DOIS_PONTOS PTO_VIRGULA
%token  APARENT FPARENT ACHAVE FCHAVE 
%token  ACOLCH FCOLCH PONTO SOMA SUB MUL
%token  DIV IGUAL DIF MENOR MENOR_IGUAL
%token  MAIOR MAIOR_IGUAL AND OR ATRIBUICAO

%left SOMA SUB
%left DIV MUL
%left USUB

%start program

%%

program:    LET comando IN exp END
            |exp

comando:    comando                         {}
            |exp                            {}
            |ifthenelse                     {}
            |atrib                          {}
            |funcao                         {}
            |record                         {}  

exp:        exp AND exp                     {}
            |exp OR exp                     {}
            |exp1                           {}

exp1:       exp2 MAIOR exp2                 {}
            |exp2 MAIOR_IGUAL exp2          {}
            |exp2 MENOR exp2                {}
            |exp2 MENOR_IGUAL exp2          {}
            |exp2 IGUAL exp2                {}
            |exp2 DIF exp2                  {}
            |exp2                           {}

exp2:       exp2 SOMA exp2                  {}
            |exp2 SUB exp2                  {}
            |SUB exp2 %prec USUB            {}
            |exp2 MUL exp2                  {}
            |exp2 DIV exp2                  {}
            |APARENT exp2 FPARENT           {}
            |INT                            {}
            |ID                             {}

ifthenelse: IF exp THEN comando ELSE comando        {}
            |IF exp THEN comando                    {}

atrib:      VAR ID ATRIBUICAO exp                   {}
            |VAR ID DOIS_PONTOS ID ATRIBUICAO exp   {}
            |VAR ID ATRIBUICAO NIL                  {}

record:     TYPE ID IGUAL STRING                    {}
            |TYPE ID IGUAL INT                      {}
            |TYPE ID IGUAL ACHAVE arg FCHAVE        {}

arg:        ID DOIS_PONTOS ID VIRGULA arg           {}
            |ID DOIS_PONTOS ID                      {}

funcao:     FUNCTION ID APARENT arg FPARENT DOIS_PONTOS ID IGUAL program {}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### No Lexer

Exitem 2 problemas:

Aqui, o token `INT` retorna um número inteiro, porém, no parser, ele espera um tipo `int`:

```
integer     {digit}+
...
{integer}       {adjust(); yylval.ival = atoi(yytext);   return INT;}
```

E aqui, ele retorna um token `STRING`:

`<INITIAL>"string"                   {adjust(); return STRING;}`

Porém, no parser, o token `STRING` está declarado como um valor `string sval;` e não como um tipo de dado.

A solução para o lexer é criar mais dois tokens que representam tipos, por exemplo:

```
<INITIAL>"string"                   { adjust(); return TSTRING;}
<INITIAL>"int"                      { adjust(); return TINT;}
```

E acrescentar as seguintes linhas **no parser**:

```
%token TSTRING
%token TINT
```

#### No parser

A gramática realmente está incorreta e é isso que está gerando o erro:

> testes/teste1:1.1: syntax error, unexpected MAIOR_IGUAL
>   **Parsing failed**

Este erro é gerado pelo parser que, provavelmente, está percorrendo um caminho
inválido ao interpretar  a gramática.

A melhor referência sobre essas ferramentas são os manuais (em inglês):

[Lexical Analysis With Flex](http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/)

[Bison 3.0.4](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html)

---

Abaixo, segue uma versão de exemplo (**bem simplificada**) do lexer/parser, que consegue reconhecer o arquivo de exemplo da pergunta:

**Lexer:**

```
 %{
#include <string.h>
#include "t.tab.h"

YYSTYPE yylval;
char err_buffer[512];

// Coloquei esta função para analisar a saída do lexer
void deb(const char *msg)
{
    // para visualizar os tokens, basta retirar o comentário abaixo
    // printf("Token: %s\n", msg);
}

%}

%option noyywrap

digit       [0-9]
letter      [a-zA-Z]
integer     {digit}+
identifier  {letter}("_"|{letter}|{digit})*
%x C_COMMENT

%%
"/*"                              { BEGIN(C_COMMENT); }
<C_COMMENT>"*/"                   { BEGIN(INITIAL); }
<C_COMMENT>.                      { deb("CM "); }
<INITIAL>"to"                     { deb("To"); return TO; }
<INITIAL>"break"                  { deb("Break"); return BREAK;}
<INITIAL>"let"                    { deb("Let"); return LET; }
<INITIAL>"in"                     { deb("In"); return IN;}
<INITIAL>"end"                    { deb("End"); return END;}
<INITIAL>"function"               { deb("Function"); return FUNCTION;}
<INITIAL>"var"                    { deb("Var"); return VAR;}
<INITIAL>"type"                   { deb("Type"); return TYPE; }
<INITIAL>"array"                  { deb("Array"); return ARRAY;}
<INITIAL>"if"                     { deb("If"); return IF;}
<INITIAL>"then"                   { deb("Then"); return THEN;}
<INITIAL>"else"                   { deb("Else"); return ELSE;}
<INITIAL>"do"                     { deb("Do"); return DO;}
<INITIAL>"of"                     { deb("Of"); return OF;}
<INITIAL>"nil"                    { deb("Nil"); return NIL;}
<INITIAL>"string"                 { deb("TString"); return TSTRING;}
<INITIAL>"int"                    { deb("TString"); return TINT;}

<INITIAL>","                      { deb("Vg"); return VIRGULA;}
<INITIAL>";"                      { deb("Pv"); return PTO_VIRGULA;}
<INITIAL>"("                      { deb("Ap"); return APARENT;}
<INITIAL>")"                      { deb("Fp"); return FPARENT;}
<INITIAL>"["                      { deb("Ac"); return ACOLCH;}
<INITIAL>"]"                      { deb("Fc"); return FCOLCH;}
<INITIAL>"{"                      { deb("Ach"); return ACHAVE;}
<INITIAL>"}"                      { deb("Fch"); return FCHAVE;}
<INITIAL>"."                      { deb("Pt"); return PONTO;}
<INITIAL>"+"                      { deb("Sm"); return SOMA;}
<INITIAL>"-"                      { deb("Sub"); return SUB;}
<INITIAL>"*"                      { deb("Mul"); return MUL;}
<INITIAL>"/"                      { deb("Div"); return DIV;}
<INITIAL>"="                      { deb("Eq"); return IGUAL;}
<INITIAL>"<>"                     { deb("Dif"); return DIF;}
<INITIAL>"<"                      { deb("Men"); return MENOR;}
<INITIAL>"<="                     { deb("Me="); return MENOR_IGUAL;}
<INITIAL>">"                      { deb("Mai"); return MAIOR;}
<INITIAL>">="                     { deb("Ma="); return MAIOR_IGUAL;}
<INITIAL>"&"                      { deb("An"); return AND;}
<INITIAL>"|"                      { deb("Or"); return OR;}
<INITIAL>":="                     { deb("Atrb"); return ATRIBUICAO;}
<INITIAL>":"                      { deb("Dp"); return DOIS_PONTOS;}

<INITIAL>{identifier}             {
                                    yylval.sval = strdup(yytext);
                                    sprintf(err_buffer, "ID[%s]\n", yylval.sval);
                                    deb(err_buffer);
                                    return ID;
                                  }

<INITIAL>[0-9][a-z]*              { printf("Erro: token ilegal[0-z].\n"); }
<INITIAL>[ \t]+                   { continue;}
<INITIAL>\n                       { deb("NL"); }
<INITIAL>[a-z]"."                 { printf("Erro: token ilegal: %s\n", yytext); }
<INITIAL>.                        { printf("Unknown character\n"); }

%%

/*

 Para executar somente o lexer, basta retirar o
 comentário abaixo 'main' e executar via pipe, exemplo:

 lexer.executavel < nome_do_arquivo.txt

 Quando for compilar novamente com o parser, comentar novamente.

*/
/*
int main()
{
    int val;
    int count = 0;

    while (val = yylex());
    printf("final.\n");
}
*/
```

Após a execução, o resultado é:

```
Token: CM
Token: CM
Token: CM
Token: CM
Token: CM
Token: CM
Token: CM
Token: CM
Token: CM
Token: CM
Token: CM


Token: NL
Token: Let
Token: NL
Token: Type
Token: ID[rectype]

Token: Eq
Token: Ach
Token: ID[name]

Token: Dp
Token: TString
Token: Vg
Token: ID[id]

Token: Dp
Token: TString
Token: Fch
Token: NL
Token: NL
Token: Var
Token: ID[a]

Token: Atrb
Token: ID[rectype]

Token: Nil
Token: NL
Token: In
Token: NL
Token: ID[a]

Token: NL
Token: End
final.
```

<sub>testado com: flex 2.5.35 e gcc version 5.1.0 (tdm64-1) [Windows 8.1]</sub>

---

**Parser:**

Uma dica: para definir a gramática (conforme o manual) é que as linhas
que possuem chamadas recursivas devem ter a primeira linha em branco. Ex:

```
comando:    /*  esta linha está em branco */
            |comando record                       { deb2("Comando record\n"); }
```

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int yylex(void); /* function prototype */

void yyerror(char *s){
    printf("%s", s);
}

// Coloquei esta função para analisar a saída do parser
void deb2(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list arg;

    va_start(arg, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, arg);
    va_end(arg);
}

%}

%union {
    int pos;
    int ival;
    char *sval;
}

%token <sval> ID
%token <sval> STRING
%token <ival> INT

%error-verbose
%token TSTRING
%token TINT
%token  TO BREAK LET IN END FUNCTION VAR
%token  TYPE ARRAY IF THEN ELSE DO OF NIL
%token  VIRGULA DOIS_PONTOS PTO_VIRGULA
%token  APARENT FPARENT ACHAVE FCHAVE
%token  ACOLCH FCOLCH PONTO SOMA SUB MUL
%token  DIV IGUAL DIF MENOR MENOR_IGUAL
%token  MAIOR MAIOR_IGUAL AND OR ATRIBUICAO

%left SOMA SUB
%left DIV MUL
%left USUB

%start program

%%

program:    LET comando IN ID END                 { deb2("Let ... ID[%s]\n", $4); }
            ;

comando:
            |comando record                       { deb2("Comando record\n"); }
            |comando atrib                        { deb2("Comando attrib\n"); }
            ;

atrib:      VAR ID ATRIBUICAO ID NIL              { deb2("Var %s := NIL\n", $2); }
            ;

record:     TYPE ID IGUAL ACHAVE arg FCHAVE       { deb2("Tipo {}\n"); }
            |TYPE ID IGUAL TSTRING                { deb2("Tipo %s : String"); }
            ;

arg:
            ID DOIS_PONTOS TSTRING VIRGULA arg    { deb2("ID[%s] : STRING,\n", $1); }
            |ID DOIS_PONTOS TINT VIRGULA arg      { deb2("ID[%s] : INT, ", $1);  }
            |ID DOIS_PONTOS TSTRING               { deb2("ID[%s] : STRING\n", $1);  }
            |ID DOIS_PONTOS TINT                  { deb2("ID[%s] : INT\n", $1);  }
            ;

%%

int main()
{
    yyparse();
}
```

Após a execução:

```
ID[id] : INT
ID[name] : STRING,
Tipo {}
Comando record
Var a := NIL
Comando attrib
Let ... ID[a]
```

<sub>testado com: bison (GNU Bison) 2.4.2 e gcc version 5.1.0 (tdm64-1) [Windows 8.1]</sub>

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, realmente faltavam essas duas coisas que você apontou. No entanto, o problema ainda continua. Esse erro acontece com qualquer token, não exclusivamente strings e int. Por exemplo, o token "LET" ele identifica como "MAIOR_IGUAL" para todo caso, da mesma forma que ele sempre identifica um "INT" como "MENOR_IGUAL". Ele sempre mantem um padrão, porém ele nunca retorna o token correto.

Comment: @FernandoL.: Dica que talvez possa ajudar: 1) neste link: [Tiger Compiler Reference](https://www.lrde.epita.fr/~tiger/tiger.html#Syntactic-Specifications) tem a definição da linguagem em formato BNF; 2) neste link: [GOLD Parsing System](http://goldparser.org/), é um gerador de parser de código aberto, com uma interface gráfica (e várias outras ferramentas no site). Apesar da sintaxe ser **diferente** do Flex/Bison, acredito que facilite bastante os testes da gramática e a visualização de problemas. Se você optar por essa solução e der certo, eu posso atualizar a resposta.