# Como fazer uma formula que esta salva em string ser calculada?

Tags: java

O usário pode digitar um formula em uma String tipo

```
String formula = (100+20+10)/50*1;
```

O que eu preciso fazer e pegar essa formula e fazer o código calculada para emitir um resultado.

Eu pensei em fazer com condições usando if ou switch case porém queria saber se existe alguma biblioteca no JAVA que faz esse tipo de coisa.
Eu expliquei de maneira simples porém o que estou fazendo envolve salvar essa formula em um banco de dados e depois que vão conter valores a serem definidos em branco dentro da formula.

Comment: E qual a fórmula desta operação?

Comment: Fica a cargo do usuário escolher a formula.

Comment: Tem que fazer um pequeno *parser*: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113578/101. Mas por sorte alguém já respondeu isto de forma genérica para qualquer linguagem. Vou fechar como duplicata.

Comment: Sua duvida não está muito clara. Se for só fazer a operação e exibir, basta um `System.out.println((100+20+10)/50*1)`.

Comment: Errou essa pergunta pega apenas parte do que preiciso @bigown por sorte achei essa outra pergunta aqui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form que resolve meu problema. Agradeço su ajuda cara.

Comment: @DiegoF, pode pareçer um exercico simples por que eu simplifiquei o maximo possivel e até seria se fosse uma calculadora simples, mais esta mais para uma formula um pouco mais complexa que envolve valores que são pegos dependendo do que a pessoa digita na formula, tipo String formula = 2+PesoDoFosfaro; esse peso do fosfaro esta salvo em um banco de dados e pode ser modificado a qualquer momento, sem contar que o usuário do sistema tem libertade para criar suas formulas de calculo da forma que bem entender. mais eu já consegui resolver meu problema obrigado.