# Expressão regular para detectar estruturas aninhadas em um template

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou tentando criar um *template engine* usando JavaScript. A sintaxe será mais ou menos parecida com a do Laravel (blade), com algumas modificações.

Estou na parte da criação das expressões. A primeira que estou fazendo é a do `if`, mas logo de cara encarei um problema.

*Antes de tudo, gostaria de deixar claro que eu criei um template num arquivo separado, que tem o conteúdo visualizado através do módulo `fs`. Para que seja possível executar no browser, coloquei toda a `string` retornada dentro de uma constante `template`:*

```
const template = `
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Um paráfrafo qualquer fora do if.</p>
  @if (true)
    <p>
      Um parágrado dentro do if.
      <strong>Tags aninhadas.</strong>
    </p>
  @endif
</div>
`;
```

Eu criei a expressão regular a seguir para fazer as buscas dentro da view:

```
/@if(?:\s+|)\(([\s\S]*?)\)([\s\S]*?)@endif/gi
```

E estou usando o seguinte código para "executar" a expressão `if`:

```
const renderView = (template, data = {}) => {
  const IF_REGEX = /@if(?:\s+|)\(([\s\S]*?)\)([\s\S]*?)@endif/gi;
  template = template.replace(IF_REGEX, (template, conditional, content) => {
    if (! eval(conditional)) return '';
    return content;
  });

  return template;
};
```

Funciona perfeitamente quando só há um bloco `if` (sem aninhamento de blocos).

No entanto, quando eu aninho dois blocos:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Parágrafo fora dos ifs.</p>

  @if (false)
    <div>Oi?</div>
    @if (true)
    <span>Span...</span>
    @endif
  @endif
</div>
```

Ele não funciona como esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso corrigir este erro? Imagino que seja na **expressão regular**.

Comment: Não use regex para esse tipo de coisa, [uma explicação boa para isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Então o que devo usar para criar esse tipo de coisa? O que Handlebars.JS ou EJS usam para criar isso? Eu quero criar o meu template-engine. Preciso de saber como fazer as buscas no HTML.

Comment: por que não olhar o [código fonte do handlebars?](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/)

Comment: Eu editei a mensagem, adicionei mais detalhes...

Comment: Expressão regular não consegue lidar com aninhamentos recursivos. O que você precisa usar aí é um [parser](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C3%A1lise_sint%C3%A1tica_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)).

Comment: Como posso fazer isso usando JavaScript? .-.

Comment: Receio que a coisa seja um pouco mais complicada do que você esperava. Isso é teorica básica de compiladores, você precisa primeiro de um [lexer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/114279/21328) que quebra o texto em tokens, depois você pega esses tokens e constrói uma árvore sintática com um parser, essa árvore é o que te da a estrutura hirarquica com as condicionais que vc quer. Para JS recomendo o [JISON](http://zaa.ch/jison/try/). Se você nunca ouviu falar de nada disso realmente vai ficar um pouco perdido, mas infelizmente não existem muitos atalhos, dê uma pesquisa sobre lexers e parsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>*Como já disseram nos comentários, não use regex, use um *parser* (ou adapte [um já existente](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/blob/master/nunjucks/src/parser.js), ou [construa um](https://www.google.com/search?q=js+parser+builder)). Regex não é a ferramenta adequada, ainda mais quando há estruturas aninhadas. Ao longo da resposta, espero que entenda os motivos, então vamos lá...*</sup>

---

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/286429/112052) pode ter funcionado para o seu caso específico, mas e se o seu *template* tiver outro `@if` depois, aí já não funciona mais:

```js
function renderView(template, data = {}) {
  const IF_REGEX = /@if(?:\s+|)\(([\s\S]*?)\)([\s\S]*?)+@endif/gi;
  template = template.replace(IF_REGEX, (template, conditional, content) => {
    if (! eval(conditional)) return '';
    return content;
  });

  return template;
}

const template = `
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Parágrafo fora dos ifs.</p>

  @if (true)
    <div>Oi?</div>
    @if (false)
    <span>Não devo ser renderizado</span>
    @endif
  @endif

  <p>Estou entre os if's</p>

  @if (true)
    <div>estou em outro if</div>
  @endif
</div>
`;

console.log(renderView(template));
```

O resultado é:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Parágrafo fora dos ifs.</p>

   
</div>
```

Que não é bem o que deveria ser - pelo que entendi, também deveria ter renderizado as tags `<div>Oi?</div>`, `<p>Estou entre os if's</p>` e `<div>estou em outro if</div>`.

Isso acontece porque a regex pegou tudo desde o primeiro `@if` até o último `@endif`. Simplesmente adicionar um quantificador ao trecho `([\s\S]*?)` só faz com que ele possa se repetir várias vezes, mas como `[\s\S]` corresponde a **qualquer coisa**, a regex pode inclusive pegar ocorrências de `@endif`, caso ache necessário.

E ao colocar o quantificador aplicado ao grupo de captura, fez com que o `content` seja vazio ([veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/D09u7d/1/), o conteúdo do Group 2 é vazio). Então o *callback* passado para `replace` acaba retornando vazio, eliminando todo o trecho entre o primeiro `@if` e o último `@endif`.

Aliás, usar `([\s\S]*?)+` é meio "estranho", pois ao usar `*?` você está indicando que `[\s\S]` deve se repetir o menor número de vezes (veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/415757/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401755/112052) para entender melhor como funciona o `*?`), mas ao circundar tudo com `+`, você está dizendo que isso pode se repetir o maior número possível de vezes (ou seja, o comportamento padrão do quantificador `+`, que é ser "ganancioso", cancela o comportamento "lazy" do `*?`, então na prática usar apenas `[\s\S]*` daria no mesmo - gerando inclusive o mesmo problema já citado acima - com a vantagem que a regex fica um pouco mais rápida, pois ao colocar quantificadores aninhados, você [aumenta as possibilidades a serem testadas](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html); já usando apenas um, há menos possibilidades e a regex tem menos casos para testar).

Outro detalhe é que `(?:\s+|)` significa "um ou mais `\s`, ou nada", então pode ser trocado para `\s*` (zero ou mais `\s`).

---

Então como eu faço para pegar os `if`'s separadamente? Com uma única regex que faz tudo de uma vez, não é possível (talvez até seja se usarmos [regex recursivas](http://rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#recursion) com [sub-rotinas](http://rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#subroutines), mas são recursos que o JavaScript não suporta).

Uma outra alternativa é tratar os `@if`'s de dentro para fora (primeiro eu verifico os mais internos, que não tem outro `@if` dentro), trato-os, atualizando o *template* e depois vou repetindo esse processo até não restar mais nenhum `@if`:

```js
function renderView(template, data = {}) {
  const IF_REGEX = /@if\s*\(((?:[\s\S](?!@if))+?)\)((?:[\s\S](?!@if))+?)@endif/gi;

  while (template.includes('@if')) { // enquanto tem @if, substitui
    template = template.replace(IF_REGEX, function(template, conditional, content) {
      if (! eval(conditional)) return '';
      return content;
    });
  }

  return template;
}

const template = `
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Parágrafo fora dos ifs.</p>
  @if (true)
    <div>Eu serei renderizado</div>
    @if (false)
    <span>Não devo ser renderizado</span>
    @endif
  @endif
  <p>Estou entre os if's</p>
  @if (true)
    <div>estou em outro if</div>
    @if (true)
      <span>Estou em um if aninhado</span>
      @if (true)
        <span>Estou em outro if aninhado</span>
        @if (false)
          <span>Não serei renderizado</span>
        @endif
      @endif
    @endif
  @endif
</div>

@if (true)<div>Eu também apareço</div>@endif
`;

console.log(renderView(template));
```

A regex usa o [*lookahead* negativo](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `[\s\S](?!@if)`, que verifica se é um caractere que não tem `@if` logo depois (e tudo isso se repete uma ou mais vezes). Aliás, troquei o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*` por `+`, pois o `*` significa "zero ou mais ocorrências", o que indica que poderia ter algo como `@if()`. Já trocando por `+` (uma ou mais ocorrências), garante que tem que ter pelo menos um caractere lá dentro (mas eu não verifico se só tem espaços, por exemplo, então `@if (   )` ainda seria aceito).

Enfim, o *lookahead* garante que vou pegar somente o `@if` que não tenha outro `@if` dentro dele. Então eu atualizo o *template* com o resultado da avaliação deste `@if`, e continuo verificando se ainda restou algum `@if` a ser analisado. Quando não tiver mais, retorna o *template* renderizado.

O resultado é (eliminando as linhas em branco, para facilitar a visualização):

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Parágrafo fora dos ifs.</p>
    <div>Eu serei renderizado</div>
  <p>Estou entre os if's</p>
    <div>estou em outro if</div>
      <span>Estou em um if aninhado</span>
        <span>Estou em outro if aninhado</span>
</div>
<div>Eu também apareço</div>
```

Mas é claro que ainda é uma implementação ingênua. Se o *template* tiver `@if` comentado (pode ter?), ele tentará avaliar (o que não ocorreria com um *parser*, já que o comentário seria detectado e corretamente ignorado). Além disso, a regex usa a [*flag* `i`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags), então o *template* poderá ter coisas como `@IF` e `@EndIf`. Se é isso mesmo que precisa, pode deixar a *flag*, senão é melhor removê-la.

Outro ponto é que dependendo do caso, muito processamento poderá ser feito à toa. Por exemplo, se o *template* for algo assim:

```
@if (condicao_falsa)
  @if (bla1)
    @if (bla2)
      @if (bla3)
        @if (bla4)
        @endif
      @endif
    @endif
  @endif
@endif
```

O algoritmo começa avaliando `bla4`, depois `bla3`, etc. Mas se as condições de todos os `@if`'s internos retornam `true` e somente a condição do primeiro mais externo retorna `false`, todos os internos terão sido renderizados à toa. Em um *parser* bem implementado, a primeira condição seria avaliada primeiro, e caso fosse falsa, nem precisaria avaliar as mais internas. Mas como já vimos que não é possível garantir com regex que sempre conseguimos pegar o `@if` mais externo, é mais uma desvantagem que você terá que se aceitar, se usar regex em vez do *parser*.

Sem contar que o próprio desempenho da regex não será *aquelas coisas*, pois ela primeiro começa a busca no `@if` mais externo, até detectar que tem outro `@if` dentro. Então ela faz o *backtracking* e tenta a partir do segundo `@if`, e depois do terceiro, etc, até encontrar o mais interno. E como está um *loop*, fará todo esse processo de novo (começa do mais externo, encontra um interno, recomeça a partir desse, etc), para cada nível de aninhamento. Para *templates* muito grandes e com muitos `@if`'s aninhados, acabará se tornando bem ineficiente, e talvez até inviável.

Também tem os casos do *template* estar com algum erro (por exemplo, um `@if` interno não tem o fechamento, então a regex acabará indo até o `@endif` do externo, coisa que um *parser* não faria porque detectaria que faltou fechar um deles), e muitas outras situações que regex não é capaz de detectar (ou até é, mas acaba ficando tão complicado que não vale a pena).

Answer (score 8):

O problema está na sua regex que irá selecionar apenas até a primeira ocorrência final em `@endif`, ignorando a segunda (ou demais).

Para resolver, adicione o *quantificador* `+` que permitirá selecionar quantas ocorrências precedidas de `@endif` que houver:

```
@if(?:\s+|)\(([\s\S]*?)\)([\s\S]*?)+@endif
                                   ↑
                             quantificador
```

Veja o print no [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/3mqmi):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]