# Diferença entre os quantificadores não gananciosos ?? e *?

Tags: r, regex

Tenho estas strings:

```
x <- c('ondasffasf', 'ondassn\nlld', 'ondas', 'ond', 'ndasss', 'das')
```

E este código com `??`:

```
library(stringr)

str_extract(x, regex('ondas??'))

[1] "onda" "onda" "onda" NA     NA     NA
```

E também com `*?`:

```
str_extract(x, regex('ondas*?'))

[1] "onda" "onda" "onda" NA     NA     NA
```

Ambos retornam o mesmo resultado. Tentei mudar as strings dentro do vetor para verificar se o resultado mudava, mas de nada adiantou.

- Qual a diferença entre os quantificadores não gananciosos `??` e `*?`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Resposta curta

Para as regex que você usou, não faz diferença. Mas há casos em que faz.

## Resposta longa

Antes vamos lembrar o que são esses [quantificadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

O `?` significa "zero ou uma ocorrência", o que é outra forma de dizer que algo é [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html). E o `*` significa "zero ou mais ocorrências" (ou seja, além de ser opcional, pode-se ter uma quantidade ilimitada).

Por *default*, eles são ["gananciosos"](http://rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) (*greedy*), ou seja, tentam pegar a maior quantidade possível de caracteres. Mas quando colocamos um `?` na frente destes (ou seja, `??` e `*?`), eles se tornam ["preguiçosos"](http://rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution) (*lazy* ou *non-greedy*), e pegam a menor quantidade **possível** de caracteres.

A questão é que a "menor quantidade possível" depende do contexto. No seu caso:

- `ondas??` quer dizer: a palavra "onda", seguida ou não de um `s`, e pegando a menor quantidade possível de `s`. Nesse caso, a menor quantidade possível é zero
- `ondas*?` quer dizer: a palavra "onda", seguida de zero ou mais letras `s`, e pegando a menor quantidade possível de `s`. Nesse caso, a menor quantidade possível também é zero

Para ambos, não importa se existem letras `s` depois de "onda". Como o quantificador é preguiçoso, ele sempre vai pegar a menor quantidade possível. E nesse caso, se eu pegar zero letras `s`, a regex já é satisfeita, por isso os *matches* encontrados em todos os casos é a string `"onda"`.

*-Mas tem um `s` depois de "onda", pega ele!*
*-Não, estou com preguiça...*

Enfim, a preguiça é isso mesmo: até tem um `s` depois, mas sem o `s` a expressão já é satisfeita, então para que pegá-lo?

---

#### Então quando faz diferença?

Usar `??` ou `*?` faz diferença se a regex tiver algo depois deles. Ex:

```
library(stringr)

x <- c('ondaX', 'ondasX', 'ondasssX', 'onda', 'ondas')

str_extract(x, regex('ondas??X'))

str_extract(x, regex('ondas*?X'))
```

<sup>[Veja aqui](https://ideone.com/b0Bg4G) este código rodando</sup>

A regex `ondas??X` procura por "onda", seguido ou não de um `s`, seguido de um `X`. Por isso ela só encontra *matches* nas duas primeiras strings:

```
[1] "ondaX"  "ondasX" NA       NA       NA
```

A primeira string ("ondaX") funciona porque é a palavra "onda", seguida de **zero** letras `s`, seguida da letra `X` (nesse caso, a menor quantidade possível de `s` que tenha um `X` logo depois é zero). A segunda string funciona porque é a palavra "onda", seguida de uma letra `s`, seguida da letra `X` (nesse caso, a menor quantidade possível de `s` que tenha um `X` logo depois é um).

A terceira string não dá *match* porque existe mais de um `s` entre "onda" e `X`. Como o quantificador `??` só pega zero ou uma letra `s`, ela não considera os casos em que há mais de um `s` (nessa string, a menor quantidade possível de `s` que tenha um `X` logo depois é 3, mas como o `??` só considera zero ou uma ocorrências, a regex não encontra um *match*).

As duas últimas não dão *match* porque não possuem um `X`.

---

Já a regex `ondas*?X` procura por "onda", seguido de zero ou mais letras `s`, seguido de `X`. Por isso ela aceita as 3 primeiras strings:

```
[1] "ondaX"    "ondasX"   "ondasssX" NA         NA
```

Todas elas tem "onda", depois tem zero ou mais `s`, e depois tem um `X`. Repare que a "menor quantidade possível" de `s` que tenha um `X` logo depois varia: na primeira string é zero, na segunda é 1 e na terceira é 3.

A regex sempre tenta várias possibilidades até encontrar a menor quantidade que satisfaça a expressão (ou até ver que não há nenhum *match*). Primeiro ela tenta com zero ocorrências de `s`. Se não der, tenta com uma, se não der, tenta com duas, e assim vai, até encontrar a menor quantidade de `s` que tenha um `X` logo depois.

---

Como nas suas regex não tinha nada depois dos `s`, a regex não precisa verificar se existe algo depois. Ela pode assumir que a menor quantidade possível que satisfaz a expressão é zero - ou seja, mesmo que tenha um `s` depois de "onda", ela não vai pegá-lo, pois a preguiça fala mais alto.

Já nos meus exemplos acima, a regex precisa verificar se tem um `X` depois dos `s`, e só vai parar quando encontrar (ou quando testar todas as possibilidades e ver que não há nenhum). Apesar de preguiçosa, ela sempre faz o que é pedido.

---

Sobre o uso do quantificador "preguiçoso", você pode ver mais casos [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401755/112052).