# Estou com problemas em pegar uma valor entre duas strings em PHP usando REGEX

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
$exemplo = "Olá, como vocês estão? Eu queria pegar o valor entre esses colchetes {# Olá mundo} e que esse aqui {#Teste} não interferisse, e me retornasse:";
```

Gostaria que o código retornasse:

```
[
   [0] => (string) "Olá mundo",
   [1] => (string) "Teste"
]
```

Meu código:

```
preg_match_all('/\{#(.*)\}/', $exemplo, $results);
vardump($results);
```

Mas ele  retorna:

```
 array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(39) "{# Olá mundo} e que esse aqui {#Teste}" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(37) "# Olá mundo} e que esse aqui {#Teste" } }
```

Comment: experimente `/\{#[^}]*)\}/` - `[^}]*` significa "tudo menos }" - Outra possibilidade `/\{#(.*?)\}/` - `*?` significa "a menor quantidade possivel" - `*?` é a versão "não fominha" do `*`

Comment: O primeiro não funcionou, porém, o segundo(/\{#(.*?)\}/ - *?) funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Se a resposta do colega CypherPotato resolver, vc pode marcar como aceita clicando no V verdinho do lado dela

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema da sua regex é que você usou o ponto, que em regex significa ["qualquer caractere" (exceto quebras de linha)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), juntamente com o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*` (que significa "zero ou mais ocorrências").

Só que por padrão os quantificadores são ["gananciosos"](http://rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) (*greedy*) e tentam pegar a maior quantidade possível de caracteres. E como o ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere (qualquer um, inclusive os próprios `{` e `}`, caso a regex ache necessário), ele acaba pegando mais texto do que você gostaria (no caso, ele pega desde o primeiro `{` até o último `}` que encontrar).

Uma das soluções já foi apontada na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/422553/112052): usar o `.*?` para tornar o quantificador ["preguiçoso"](http://rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution) (*lazy*), assim ele passa a pegar a menor quantidade possível de caracteres - ou seja, ele só vai até o primeiro `}` que encontrar (mais detalhes sobre quantificadores *lazy* [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/415774/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401755/112052)).

---

Mas eu gostaria de sugerir outra solução (que já foi dada [nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/422551/estou-com-problemas-em-pegar-uma-valor-entre-duas-strings-em-php-usando-regex#comment820726_422551), mas de qualquer forma vou detalhá-la melhor).

Em vez de usar o ponto (que pega qualquer caractere), você pode ser mais específico e [indicar exatamente o que precisa](http://rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want). No caso, você não quer qualquer caractere, e sim "qualquer caractere que **não** seja o `}`". Para isso usamos uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated): `[^}]` (que significa "qualquer caractere que não seja `}`"). Repare que não precisei usar o escape `\}`, pois dentro de colchetes muitos metacaracteres não precisam da `\`. O código ficaria assim:

```
$exemplo = "Olá, como vocês estão? Eu queria pegar o valor entre esses colchetes {# Olá mundo} e que esse aqui {#Teste} não interferisse, e me retornasse:";
preg_match_all('/\{#([^}]+)\}/', $exemplo, $results);
foreach ($results[1] as $texto) {
    echo $texto.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Repare que troquei o quantificador `*` por `+`. No caso, o `*` significa "**zero** ou mais ocorrências", o que quer dizer que se não tiver nada entre o `#` e o `}`, a regex também aceitaria (e viria uma string vazia nos resultados). Já o `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências", obrigando que haja pelo menos um caractere entre o `#` e o `}`.

Também coloco o trecho `[^}]+` entre parênteses para formar um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). E como é o primeiro par de parênteses da regex, este trecho estará no grupo 1 (que por sua vez estarão na posição 1 do array `$results`). Percorrendo o array `$results[1]`, eu obtenho todos os textos capturados. A saída é:

```
 Olá mundo
Teste
```

Repare que ela inclui o espaço antes de "Olá mundo", já que a regex pega tudo entre o `#` e o `}`.

---

O detalhe é que esta regex também captura textos como `{#abc{xyz}` (no caso, ela captura o trecho "abc{xyz"). Se não quiser que pegue o `{` entre o `c` e o `x`, pode incluir o `{` na classe de caracteres negados, ficando `/\{#([^{}]+)\}/` - agora estou dizendo que quero `[^{}]` (qualquer coisa que **não** seja `{` nem `}`).

Outro detalhe (que neste caso eu admito que não passa de micro-otimização, mas mesmo assim vale comentar) é que usar `[^{}]` deixa a regex um pouco mais rápida do que se usar o ponto. Compare [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/6wbpP5/1/) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/Yd04KZ/3/) a quantidade de passos de cada regex. **Obviamente** que para poucas strings pequenas, a diferença será insignificante (provavelmente será de milissegundos ou até menos), mas se for tratar um grande volume de dados, dependendo das strings e da regex, o uso de `.*?` [pode levar a resultados catastróficos](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Isso acontece porque o quantificador *lazy*, apesar de conveniente, [cobra o seu preço](http://rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_expensive). Ao encontrar `.*?\}`, a regex primeiro tenta encontrar um *match* com zero caracteres (ou seja, verifica se o próximo já é o `}`). Se não der, tenta com um caractere e vê se o segundo é `}`. Se não der, tenta com dois caracteres e vê se o terceiro é `}`, e assim por diante, até encontrar um `}`. Esse vai e vem é chamado de *backtracking*, e dependendo do caso, pode ser bem custoso. Já ao usar `[^{}]+`, a regex pode avançar "sem medo" - e sem *backtracking* - pois ela vai parar assim que encontrar um `{` ou `}`. Evitando o *backtracking* e garantindo que ela para no ponto correto, eu a torno mais eficiente (isso explica a diferença de passos nos links acima - e conforme o texto aumenta, a proporção entre a quantidade de passos aumenta ainda mais, veja [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/6wbpP5/3/) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/Yd04KZ/5/)).

Entendo que usar `.*` pareça mais fácil, e para casos mais simples "funciona", mas só use se você realmente quiser "qualquer coisa". Não é o caso da pergunta, pois na verdade você queria qualquer caractere que não fossem as chaves.

---

Outra diferença é que o ponto, por padrão, não pega as quebras de linha. Ou seja, se o texto tiver algo como:

```
{#texto em
várias
linhas}
```

A regex com `.*?` não pega porque ela desconsidera as quebras de linha. Mas é possível mudar este comportamento, adicionando a [*flag*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) `s` na regex:

```
// com a flag "s", o ponto pega também as quebras de linha
preg_match_all('/\{#(.*?)\}/s', $exemplo, $results);
                            ^ aqui
```

Já usando `[^{}]`, as quebras de linhas já são consideradas, sem precisar da *flag* `s`. Neste caso, se **não** quiser pegar as quebras de linha, basta incluí-las na classe de caracteres negados:

```
// incluir \n e \r para não pegar as quebras de linha
preg_match_all('/\{#([^{}\n\r]+)\}/', $exemplo, $results);
```

Answer (score 4):

É isso mesmo, mas com uma pequena adição:

```
\{#(.*?)\}
```

O caractere `?` logo depois de um `*` significa "a menor quantidade possível", contrário do `*` sozinho, que é "o máximo que puder". Depois deste grupo ele procura o próximo match, que é o `}`.

Outra possibilidade é capturar o conteúdo que está dentro dos `{ ... }` sem as chaves, com:

```
(?<=\{).+?(?=\})
```

Isso irá capturar `# Olá mundo` e `#Teste` na string usada.

Comment: Obtive o seguinte erro:
Warning: preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in.
Porém, já resolvi meu problema, de qualquer modo, muito obrigado!

Comment: @Sydo vc lembrou de por os / / em volta? Note que os / / nao fazem parte da RegEx, são os delimitadores. Na sua pergunta tem `/\{#(.*)\}/`, mas a regEx mesmo é o `\{#(.*)\}` - de qq forma precisa por os `/` ou outro caractere não usado na expressão

Comment: Você tem razão, funcionou ao colocá-los. Obrigado novamente, e obrigado também @CypherPotato

Comment: Olá Cypher, eu tenho outra dúvida, se não for incomodo, você poderia me informar um regex que pegue valores dentro da tag php? `<?php valor ?>`

Comment: @Sydo Você poderia tentar algo como `/\<\?php(.*?)\?\>/gms`. Note que deverá usar a tag `single-line` no código.