# Regex para pegar um trecho que pode ou não ocorrer

Tags: c#, regex

Tenho uma frase, onde antes e ao final dela eu tenho `{{` e `}}`

Exemplo: `{{UMA FRASE DE EXEMPLO}}`

Em alguns casos, eu posso ter um parâmetro para essa frase. Para identificar que tem um parâmetro eu uso `_`, então eu teria:
`{{UMA FRASE DE EXEMPLO}}_(123)`

Atualmente eu faço assim para pegar a frase entre os `{{` e `}}`

```
var command = "{{UMA FRASE AQUI}} + {{OUTRA FRASE AQUI}}_(123)";
Regex r = new Regex(@"\{\{[^\}]+?\}\}");
var m = r.Matches(command);
```

O `m` me retorna 2 contagens:

`m[1] = {{UMA FRASE AQUI}}`

`m[2] = {{OUTRA FRASE AQUI}}`

Quando eu tiver o `_` eu preciso que fique assim:

`m[2] = {{OUTRA FRASE AQUI}}_(123)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta fazer com que a parte depois do `_` seja opcional:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\{\{[^\}]+?\}\}(_\(\d+\))?");
```

Estou assumindo que o ID é numérico, por isso usei `\d+` (um ou mais dígitos). Os parênteses em volta do número devem ser escapados com `\`, e em volta de tudo isso eu coloco parênteses para agrupar tudo e deixar todo este trecho opcional, usando `?` (a interrogação torna todo o trecho `(_\(\d+\))` [opcional](http://regular-expressions.info/optional.html)).

---

Se o ID pode ter letras e números, uma alternativa é trocar  `\d` por `\w`:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\{\{[^\}]+?\}\}(_\(\w+\))?");
```

Se bem que o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w` também considera o caractere `_`, então strings como `___` e `__1__` serão consideradas válidas. Se não quiser que considere o `_`, pode trocar para:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\{\{[^\}]+?\}\}(_\([a-zA-Z\d]+\))?");
```

A [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[a-zA-Z\d]` considera letras de `a` a `z` (maiúsculas e minúsculas), além de dígitos (`\d`). Mas esta regex não considera letras acentuadas, e neste caso você ainda poderia usar:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\{\{[^\}]+?\}\}(_\([\p{L}\d]+\))?");
```

O atalho `\p{L}` considera todos os caracteres definidos pelo Unicode, que estejam nas categorias "Letter" (todas [desta lista](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm), que começam com "L"), ou seja, além das letras acentuadas, também considera letras de outros alfabetos (árabe, japonês, cirílico, etc).

Enfim, são várias opções e qual usar depende muito de como estão os seus dados. Se você sabe, por exemplo, que não há casos como `__1__` e todos os IDs são válidos, usar somente `\w` (ou `[a-zA-Z\d]`, caso não haja letras com acento) pode ser o suficiente.

---

Outro detalhe é que no trecho `[^\}]+?` você não precisa da interrogação. Neste caso ele serve para deixar o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` ["preguiçoso"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/415774/112052), mas como você está buscando por `[^\}]` (qualquer coisa que não seja `}`) e logo em seguida há o próprio caractere `}`, não há risco da regex avançar além do necessário (que é um dos principais motivos de se usar quantificadores preguiçosos).

Então esse `?` logo depois do `+` pode ser removido:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\{\{[^\}]+\}\}(_\(\d+\))?");
```

Comment: eu coloquei como sempre fosse numerico, mas pode ser caracter tambem, pode me mostrar como ficaria?

Comment: @LeoHenrique Atualizei a resposta

Comment: obrigado pela explicação completa :)

Comment: preciso de uma ajuda, tenho outro cenario, posso ter, alem do que esta na pergunta, este caso `(123,abc,456)`, pode me dizer como faria? (pode ser misturado letras e numeros)

Comment: @LeoHenrique Talvez `@"\{\{[^\}]+\}\}(_\(\w+(,\w+)*\))?"` já sirva. Ou `@"\{\{[^\}]+\}\}(_\((\d+|[a-z]+)(,(\d+|[a-z]+))*\))?"` - não testei, mas deve resolver

Comment: Usei este: `@"\{\{[^\}]+\}\}(_\(\w+(,\w+)*\))?"` e funcionou... Obrigado