# Como dividir uma string em blocos e retorná-las com BASH_REMATCH

Tags: regex, bash, shell-script, shell, sh

Tentei splitar uma string com nome de arquivo, em 5 partes.
Com o código e regex abaixo, consigo o bloco 1 e bloco 5.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

str="python-zope-proxy-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst"
pkg_re='(.+)-[^-]+-[0-9]+-([^.]+)\.chi.zst*'

[[ $str =~ $pkg_re ]] && 
   pkg_base=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} 
   pkg_arch=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}

echo $pkg_base
echo $pkg_arch
```

Porém, o regex teria que retornar os blocos na seguinte forma:

```
bloco 1 - python-zope-proxy # pkg_base
bloco 2 - 4.3.5-1           # pkg_version_build
bloco 3 - 4.3.5             # pkg_version
bloco 4 - 1                 # pkg_build
bloco 5 - x86_64            # pkg_arch
```

O regex teria que tratar a string também nos seguintes casos de nome de arquivo:

```
str="python-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst"
str="python-zope-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst"
str="python-zope-proxy-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst"
```

Comment: Tente usar a expressão `([a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+){,2})-(([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){,2})((\-)([0-9]+))?)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+).*` e os índices `1`, `3`, `4`, `8` e `9` do *array* `BASH_REMATCH`, respectivamente.

Comment: @Rfroes87 Teu código funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado

Comment: Ótimo! Quando possível, peço que confira ambas respostas (minha e do @MarceloVismari) e aceite a resposta que melhor atende ao que você necessita, por favor.

Comment: Importante nestes casos dizer o que tentou (um [mcve] preferencialmente) e a dificuldade encontrada.  Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e depois o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Comment: @Bacco, discordo em relação ao equivocado fechamento, alegando falta de exemplos; tanto a pergunta quanto as respostas foram claras, tanto que foi entendida de primeira e postado resposta até com exemplos.

Comment: @vcatafesta não foi equivocado não, se fosse a comunidade já teria votado pra reabrir em seguida. O sistema é projetado para isso. Talvez [depois da edição feita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/480262/revisions) (que a comunidade tem acesso ao histórico completo) a comunidade possa reconsiderar, mas ainda falta explicar o que tentou para resolver e não deu certo. De qualquer forma, se der uma estudada nos links que passei talvez entenda melhor o objetivo do site e a razão do fechamento.

Comment: O título também poderia ser melhor trabalhado.

Comment: P.ex. ***Como agrupar substrings em condição e retorná-las com BASH_REMATCH*** ou algo do gênero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como alternativa à solução provida pelo usuário @MarceloVismari, aqui está uma expressão regular compatível com `bash` 4.2+:

```
str="python-zope-proxy-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst"

if [[ $str =~ ([a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)-(([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*)(-([0-9]+))?)-([^.]+).* ]]; then
  for group_num in "${!BASH_REMATCH[@]}"; do
    echo "group ${group_num}: ${BASH_REMATCH[$group_num]}"
  done
fi
```

Cujo *output* é:

```
group 0: python-zope-proxy-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst
group 1: python-zope-proxy
group 2: -proxy
group 3: 4.3.5-1
group 4: 4.3.5
group 5: .5
group 6: -1
group 7: 1
group 8: x86_64
```

Os grupos de interesse neste exemplo seriam os `1`, `3`, `4`, `7` e `8`.

EDIT 1: Modificado quantificador `+` (1 ou mais caracteres) para `*` (0 ou mais caracteres) em sufixo de `pkg_base` (primeiro `-` em diante após `python`, no exemplo) e `pkg_version`/`pkg_version_build` (primeiro `.` em diante após `4`, no exemplo).

EDIT 2: Destrinchando a *regex* proposta:

- **`([a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)` -** Captura de grupo raiz iniciando com uma *string* de 1 ou mais caracteres (`[a-zA-Z0-9]+`) e terminando com um subgrupo opcional (`(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*`) iniciando com um hífen e seguido de uma *string* de 1 ou mais caracteres
  ***Isso deveria corresponder a `python-zope-proxy`, `python-zope-proxy-lorem-ipsum-dolor...` (tendendo ao infinito) ou apenas `python`***
- **`(([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*)(-([0-9]+))?)` -** Captura de grupo raiz iniciando com um subgrupo contendo um número inteiro de 1 ou mais dígitos (`[0-9]+`), um subgrupo aninhado opcional (`(\.[0-9]+)*`) iniciando com um ponto (`\.`) e seguido por um número inteiro de 1 ou mais dígitos; fechado o primeiro subgrupo, inicia-se um novo subgrupo opcional (`(-([0-9]+))?`, com o quantificador `?` indicando 0 ou 1 ocorrências) começado por um hífen e seguido por um subgrupo aninhado contendo um número inteiro de 1 ou mais dígitos.
  ***Isso deveria corresponder a `4.3.5`, `4.3.5-1`, `4` ou `4-1`. Tomando `4.3.5-1` como exemplo, esta parte da expressão regular estaria agrupando `4.3.5-1`, `4.3.5` e `1` em subgrupos dedicados (os 2 subgrupos adjacentes ao raiz)***
- **`([^.]+)` -** Captura de grupo raiz iniciando com uma [`lista negada`](https://aurelio.net/regex/guia/lista-negada.html) e capturando 1 ou mais caracteres quaisquer.
  ***Isso deveria corresponder a qualquer tamanho e tipo de caracteres até parar no caractere `.` (ou no fim da *string*); p.ex. `x86_64` (`x86_64.chi.zst`), `x86` (`x86.zst`), `x64` (`x64.chi`), `x` (`x`), etc.***

EDIT 3: Adicionado *output* de execução de código `bash` apresentado na solução.

EDIT 4: Conforme @hkotsubo mencionou em seu comentário, tanto os quantificadores `*` como `+` são classificados como *greedy*; quantificadores *non-greedy* ou **não gananciosos** - entre outras informações pertinentes a quantificadores em geral - estão descritos em maiores detalhes em suas respostas das perguntas [Diferença entre os quantificadores não gananciosos ?? e *?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/415757/112052) e [Expressões Regulares: função do quantificador lazy “?”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401755/112052).

Comment: na expressão acima, deu match nos seguintes casos:
str="python-zope-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst"                                                                                                                                                                            str="python-zope-proxy-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst" 

porém no seguinte, falha:
str="python-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst"

No entanto, esta expressão funciona em todos os casos:
([a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+){,2})-(([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){,2})((\-)([0-9]+))?)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+).*

Comment: @vcatafesta Atualizei a resposta. Teste novamente e me dê um feedback caso tenha mais algum problema.

Comment: show agora! Obrigado

Comment: Atualizei a resposta para conter mais detalhes sobre a composição da expressão regular que propus.

Comment: Na verdade tanto `+` quanto `*` e `?` são greedy, o que muda é só a quantidade: `+` é "1 ou mais vezes", `*` é "zero ou mais vezes" e `?` é "zero ou 1 vez" (que é outra forma de dizer "opcional"), mas todos são greedy (tentam pegar a maior quantidade possível, dentro dos seus limites). Para ser non-greedy teria que ser `+?`, `*?` e `??`. Entenda a diferença [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/415757/112052)  e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401755/112052)

Comment: @hkotsubo Notado, grato pela correção! Há um tempo eu venho usando quantificadores não gananciosos em minhas expressões regulares (principalmente `*?`) e acabei misturando a nomenclatura na minha cabeça devido ao fato de `*` tornar o padrão opcional. Estarei editando a resposta de acordo com suas observações.

Answer (score 0):

Para atender os mais críticos, segue a conversão do exemplo em JS para bash:

```
str="python-zope-proxy-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst"
pkg_re='^([a-z-]+)(-)([0-9\\.]+)(-)([0-9])(-)(.*)(.chi.zst)$'

[[ $str =~ $pkg_re ]] &&
    pkg_base=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    pkg_version=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    pkg_build=${BASH_REMATCH[5]}
    pkg_arch=${BASH_REMATCH[7]}

echo $pkg_base
echo $pkg_version
echo $pkg_build
echo $pkg_arch
```

Comment: funfou liso também tua expressao em todos os cases:
str="python2-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst"                                                                                                                                                                 str="python-zope-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst"                                                                                                                                                            str="python-zope-proxy-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst" 

o que faltou, concatenar não será problema. Obrigado.