# Regex extrair substring de texto delimitada por um padrão de fim que se repete no texto (STARTtextoFIM STARTtextoFIM)

Tags: string, regex

Tenho como objetivo realizar a extração da substring delimitada por `ENTER` e `Tempo de viagem total:4h 05m` no texto abaixo:

Para isso construi a seguinte expressão regular: `ENTER[\S\s]+Tempo de viagem total:.*h .*m` (geral pra funcionar em qualquer texto)

Contudo quando efetuada a extração no texto abaixo :

```
ENTERAZUL Linhas Aereas Brasileiras - 4884
ENTERAerospatiale/Alenia ATR 72
ENTERFev
ENTER1
ENTERBauru, SP, BR
ENTERSao Paulo, SP, BR
ENTER19:50JTC
ENTER20:50VCP
ENTERMoussa Nakhl Tobias Airport
ENTERViracopos International Airport
ENTER1h 00m
ENTEReconômica
ENTERExecutiva
ENTER1h 25m escala · Sao Paulo, SP, BR
ENTERAZUL Linhas Aereas Brasileiras - 4663
ENTERUnknown Aircraft
ENTERFev
ENTER1
ENTERSao Paulo, SP, BR
ENTERBrasilia, DF, BR
ENTER22:15VCP
ENTER23:55BSB
ENTERViracopos International Airport
ENTERBrasilia International Airport
ENTER1h 40m
ENTEReconômica
ENTERExecutiva
ENTEREmissões de CO2:econômica/Econômica "Premium": 154kg
ENTERExecutiva: 195kg
ENTERTempo de viagem total:4h 05m
ENTERAZUL Linhas Aereas Brasileiras - 4399
ENTERUnknown Aircraft
ENTERFev
ENTER5
ENTERBrasilia, DF, BR
ENTERSao Paulo, SP, BR
ENTER05:25BSB
ENTER07:05VCP
ENTERBrasilia International Airport
ENTERViracopos International Airport
ENTER1h 40m
ENTEReconômica
ENTERExecutiva
ENTER2h 25m escala · Sao Paulo, SP, BR
ENTERAZUL Linhas Aereas Brasileiras - 4530
ENTERAerospatiale/Alenia ATR 72
ENTERFev
ENTER5
ENTERSao Paulo, SP, BR
ENTERBauru, SP, BR
ENTER09:30VCP
ENTER10:35JTC
ENTERViracopos International Airport
ENTERMoussa Nakhl Tobias Airport
ENTER1h 05m
ENTEReconômica
ENTERExecutiva
ENTEREmissões de CO2:econômica/Econômica "Premium": 154kg
ENTERExecutiva: 195kg
ENTERTempo de viagem total:5h 10m
```

O match do delimitador final da substring é feito com `Tempo de viagem total:5h 10m` ao invés de `Tempo de viagem total:4h 05m` resultando na não separação do texto, como se a busca do delimitador final estivesse sendo realizada do fim do texto para o começo.

Existe alguma forma de realizar este tipo de busca em texto procurando pela primeira ocorrência do delimitador final ? (neste exemplo primeira ocorrência de `Tempo de viagem total:.*h .*m` )

Estou utilizando o site https://regexr.com/ para testar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, uma explicação sobre `[\S\s]`: este é um "truque" conhecido para pegar "qualquer caractere". Geralmente usa-se o ponto para "qualquer caractere", mas por padrão, [o ponto não considera quebras de linha](http://regularexpressions.info/dot.html), então `[\S\s]` acaba sendo uma alternativa, pois ele pega `\s` (um [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) para espaços, TABs, quebras de linha, [entre outros caracteres](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052)) e `\S` (tudo que não é `\s`). Ou seja, `[\S\s]` pega qualquer caractere, incluindo quebras de linha.

Já o [quantificador `+`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) significa "uma ou mais ocorrências", mas por padrão, os quantificadores são "gananciosos" e [tentam pegar a maior quantidade possível de caracteres](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap). E qual a maior quantidade possível de caracteres que logo depois tem o `Tempo de viagem total etc...`? A string inteira, por isso ele pega até o `5h 10m`.

Uma maneira de resolver é tornar o quantificador `+` ["preguiçoso"](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution), colocando um `?` na frente: `[\S\s]+?`. Assim, ele pega a menor quantidade possível de caracteres, neste caso, indo até o `4h 05m`.

Outro detalhe é que você está usando `.*h .*m`, mas `.*` significa "zero ou mais caracteres", o que significa que ele também pegaria coisas como `h m` ou `abch xyzm`. Se quer restringir para apenas números, pode usar `\d+h \d+m` (`d+` significa "um ou mais dígitos"), ou se quiser controlar a quantidade, pode usar `\d{1,2}h \d{1,2}m` (no caso, `\d{1,2}` significa "no mínimo 1, no máximo 2 dígitos"). Assim você garante que deve ter pelo menos um dígito.

Pode até ser que "funcione" com `.*`, mas muitas vezes você não quer "qualquer coisa", e sim algo mais específico (neste caso, me parece que apenas dígitos seriam válidos, então não é "qualquer coisa"), e em regex [é melhor ser específico com relação ao que você quer e também ao que não quer](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want).

Resumindo, a regex ficaria `ENTER[\S\s]+?Tempo de viagem total:\d+h \d+m`.

---

No caso de sites como o RegExr, você também poderia usar o ponto em vez de `[\S\s]`, e habilitar a *flag single line*:

[image: RegExr com flag singleline habilitada]

Assim, o ponto também considera quebras de linha ([veja aqui](https://regexr.com/5h735)), substituindo o `[\S\s]`. Neste caso, a expressão ficaria `ENTER.+?Tempo de viagem total:\d+h \d+m`.

---

Para entender melhor sobre quantificadores gananciosos ("greedy") e preguiçosos ("lazy"), leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/415757/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401755/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/482807/112052).

---

Vale lembrar que este problema seria - na minha opinião - mais fácil de resolver sem regex, usando alguma linguagem de programação. Assim você poderia ler linha a linha, ver se ela é o início de um registro ou o final (se ela contém "Tempo de viagem total", por exemplo), e ir concatenando as linhas em um único registro. [Regex nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso, faltou apenas inserir o ponto de interrogação logo após o sinal de mais:

```
ENTER[\S\s]+?Tempo de viagem total:.*h .*m
```

Isso faz que o motor de busca avalie sua expressão no **modo lazy**, ao invés do **modo greedy**.

Assim, caso vc queira obter todas as matches (2 no caso do texto compartilhado), use a flag global na sua expressão. Caso queira apenas a primeira match, não use a flag global.