# Lookahead negativo não impede que encontre um match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

O que está errado com essa expressão regular?

```
preg_match_all('/{{.*?(?!\|e)}}/',$content,$matches);
```

No texto abaixo ele não deveria pegar o `{{Expression|e}}` já que estou negando o `|e` no grupo `(?!\|e)`

> Edit the {{Expression|e}} & Text to see matches. Roll over matches
> or the expression for details. PCRE & JavaScript {{flavors}} of RegEx are
> supported. {{Validate}} your expression with Tests mode.

Como deveria ser a expressão certa para que os *matches* fossem apenas `{{flavors}}` e `{{Validate}}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, sobre `.*?`: o ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere, e o `*?` é um quantificador *lazy*, que pega zero ou mais caracteres, mas sempre a menor quantidade possível que satisfaça a expressão.

O funcionamento detalhado é explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/482807/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/415757/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401755/112052), mas basicamente funciona assim:

Supondo o caso de `Expression|e`, primeiro a regex tenta um match com zero caracteres antes do `}`. Como tem mais de um, ela volta e tenta com somente o "E".

Como depois do "E" não tem "}", ela tenta com "Ex", e assim por diante. Quando chega no "n", o *lookahead* vê que depois tem `|e` e falha, só que como o ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere, ela continua tentando.

Então a próxima tentativa é com "Expression|", ela vê que depois não tem "}", e por fim tenta com "Expression|e", vê que depois não tem `|e` e tem "}", e retorna o *match*.

Isso acontece porque a expressão quer dizer "zero ou mais caracteres (`.*?`), desde que não tenha "|e" depois". O problema é que o ponto pega **qualquer caractere**, inclusive o próprio `|` e também o `e`. Pode parecer contraditório e contraintuitivo, mas é assim que a *engine* funciona.

Se a ideia é não permitir `|e` dentro dos colchetes, então o *lookahead* deve estar dentro da repetição:

```php
preg_match_all('/{{([^}](?!\|e))+}}/',$content,$matches);
```

No caso, `[^}]` é "qualquer caractere que **não** seja `}`" e o *lookahead* fica logo depois. Ou seja, é um único caractere, desde que depois não tenha `|e`.

E tudo isso se repete várias vezes: coloquei tudo entre parênteses e usei o quantificador `+`, que indica uma ou mais ocorrências. O `*` indica "zero ou mais ocorrências", ou seja, também pega casos como `{{}}`. Já usando `+` eu forço que tenha pelo menos um caractere entre os colchetes.

Portanto a regex agora é "qualquer caractere que não seja `}`, desde que não tenha `|e` depois, tudo isso repetido uma ou mais vezes".

Um detalhe é que os parênteses formam um grupo de captura, que acabam "ocupando espaço" no array de *matches*. Se não quiser esses dados a mais (e somente o *match* completo), basta trocar para grupos de não-captura, colocando `(?:`:

```php
preg_match_all('/{{(?:[^}](?!\|e))+}}/',$content,$matches);
```

Comment: Show, muito obrigado, na verdade só acrescentei uma } depois de e para evitar que ele escape ee ou escape, ou seja, obrigando a depois do e ter }

Ficou assim preg_match_all('/{{([^}](?!\|e}))+}}/',$content,$matches);