# O que é um construtor da linguagem?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem

Em PHP, já li e ouvi várias vezes a respeito dos Construtores da Linguagem. Os casos que sempre ouvi falar deles foi em casos onde se dizia: "prefira usar X ao invés de Y, pois Y é uma função e X é um construtor da linguagem".

Um dos casos que já li algo a respeito seria no caso de usar `isset` pra checar um índice de um `array`, ao invés de `array_keys_exists` (*sei bem a diferença entre os dois, mas não é o foco da pergunta*). A recomendação é porque `array_key_exists` é uma função, e `isset`, um construtor.

Sendo assim, eu queria saber algumas coisa:

- O que seria um construtor da linguagem em PHP? Quais são eles?
- Por que a documentação do PHP recomenda, em alguns casos, usar construtores da linguagem ao invés das funções?
- Nos casos em que os construtores da linguagem se assemelham às funções (como `isset`, `empty` e `require`), quais são as principais diferenças entre os Construtores da linguagem e as funções?

Um exemplo da pergunta 2: usar `isset` ao invés de `is_null` (que é uma função), onde `isset` também retorna `True` caso o valor da variável seja `NULL`.

Comment: isset não verifica se é null apenas mas se a variável em si existe, quando você cria uma variável ela ocupa endereço na memória, mas o valor do conteúdo dela pode ser nulo. Nesse caso se usar o isset ele será vai retornar true, não porque não é nulo, mas porque ela existe em algum lugar da memória, o is_null pressupõe que a variável existe e testa o valor dela, não se ela está alocada em algum lugar. Se a variável não for sequer instanciada o isset vai retornar falso, não porque ela é nula, mas porque não ocupa endereço na memória.

Comment: construtor em php é um método usado para definir os parâmetros padrão do seu objeto, quando você cria uma classe em qualquer linguagem você na realidade está pedindo ao sistema operacional ou ao gerenciador de memoria, que reserve um espaço especifico da memória (o necessário para alocar os atributos e demais recursos do seu objeto), feito isso o construtor permitir definir os valores padrão para o seu objeto e te devolve o endereço que ele alocou para aquele objeto.

Comment: O PHP assim como outras linguagens, recomenda que use construtores não porque você deva sempre fazer aquilo, mas porque muitas das vezes você pode estar usando um recurso de forma errada, por não saber exatamente para o que ele serve.

Comment: @SilenoBrito **Errado**. `isset` verifica se a variável existe e se ela não é `NULL`. Veja na [documentação](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). Muita gente que usa PHP acha exatamente o que você falou, mas estão errados. A documentação deixa bem claro: **Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL**. Claro, a documentação em português também não ajuda.

Comment: Sobre construtor: Errado novamente. Não estou falando de construtor de uma classe, estou falando de "Construtor da linguagem" (Languange construct), que são as famosas "palavras reservadas".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> O que seria um construtor da linguagem em PHP? Quais são eles?

Alguns não gostarão disto, mas eu tenho que dizer que costuma ser gambiarra, pelo menos a maioria dos casos em PHP.

Tudo que o compilador trata de forma especial podemos considerar como construção da linguagem (não gosto do termo construtor aí porque ele não é bem um agente e sim uma característica, então vou usar construção). Uma função de forma geral é uma construção da linguagem, porque ela trata de forma especial. Digo, a criação de função em si é uma construção. O `if` é uma construção. Mas usar uma função é algo do usuário, mesmo que seja uma função padrão da biblioteca já não pertence à linguagem, a função não tem significado especial.

> Por que a documentação do PHP recomenda, em alguns casos, usar construtores da linguagem ao invés das funções?

Acredito que por ela ter mais eficiência, ou porque já está pronto, ou porque é a única opção mesmo (depende do caso). De fato uma construção pode ser mais eficiente porque o compilador/interpretador pode tratar de forma melhor do que uma função poderia, mas em certas linguagens isso não ocorre ou não é necessário, ou o ganho é irrisório. Curiosamente linguagens de *script*, como é o caso de PHP, não precisam muito de otimizações e uma função seria adequada. Construções de linguagem podem ser úteis quando o compilador pode garantir um código *target* melhor. E curiosamente essas linguagens tem capacidade de otimizar funções a tal ponto que torna a construção desnecessária. Então podemos falar em falha do compilador do PHP também.

Embora hoje eu acho que tem muito disso por legado. Hoje talvez fariam diferente. Ou não, afinal em toda versão desta linguagem colocam coisas ruins novas.

> Nos casos em que os construtores da linguagem se assemelham às funções (como `isset`, `empty` e `require`), quais são as principais diferenças entre os Construtores da linguagem e as funções?

O `require` eu acho que deve ser construção mesmo porque ele muda o código fonte que está sendo trabalhando ali, tem uma influência maior na execução, mas em PHP muda menos. Note que ele pode ser usado até sem parênteses, assim como o `echo` e outros assim podem ser usados sem.

Quem sabe o fato de não obrigar os parênteses tenha sido o motivo para preferir ser construção da linguagem. Tem linguagem que permite deixá-los de lado em alguns casos de funções sem que precise ser construção de linguagem.

O `empty()` por exemplo provavelmente pode ter alguma otimização porque ela trata de vários tipos e aí teria um enorme `switch` para selecionar a ação de acordo com o argumento usado e isto teria um custo, mesmo que nem sempre expressivo porque a maioria dos tipos estaria no início da tabela e as verificações não são, ou não deveriam ser feitas uma a uma, mas vai saber se o `switch` do PHP não é otimizado assim.

O `isset()` pode ser porque envolve coisas internas da linguagem, mas poderia ser sim uma função.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: **Adendo**: Quando o é uma construção da linguagem, não é possível armazenar o  nome em uma variável para usar através de `call_user_func` ou `$f = 'isset'; $f($var)`.

Comment: Certamente.....

Comment: Desculpe mas não consigo enxergar como o construtor de uma linguagem pode ser considerada uma gambiarra. Também não consegui enxergar que o objetivo de um construtor seria para obter mais eficiência ou ainda que não é necessário ter otimização em linguagens de script. Sua resposta foi quase toda baseada em "não sei" e "eu acho".

Comment: @SilenoBrito poste a sua resposta dizendo o que é. Eu sei que é isto, dentro do conhecimento que tenho em mais de 30 anos estudando linguagens de programação. Não tem informações oficiais sobre isto, mas é de conhecimento público que essas construções são desnecessárias e podem ser só funções feitos da maneira certa, e tem várias postagens pela web argumento sobre essas e outras gambiarras do PHP. Também é de conhecimento universal que *scripts* não precisam de performance. Se tem um motivo claro pela escolha de fazer assim deveria estar documentado. Provavelmente não há porque não tem motivo.

Comment: E pelo que percebi você está falando de outra coisa completamente diferente do que trata a pergunta. Se começar falar da mesma coisa, talvez também comece fazer sentido. Ninguém está falando de construtor de classe aqui. Releia a pergunta e a resposta para entender sobre o que é. Depois disso é para fazer mais sentido. Se ainda não fizer mostre nos seus comentários ou resposta porque discorda dessas coisas, se ainda discordar. Estamos falando aqui sobre decisões de *design* de linguagem, e até de forma bem específica em qual mecanismo, e não sobre mecanismos de classes.

Comment: @Maniero tinha razão, estavamos falando de coisas diferentes, postei uma resposta com base no que eu conheço que pode não ser muito. Os comentários que fiz no post realmente não se aplicam, pois realmente me confundi com o título e o post, agradeço por ter me alertado. Contudo mesmo eu tendo errado antes, após reler, ainda não concordo com suas afirmações. Os motivo são os mesmos que eu comentei anteriormente.

Comment: @SilenoBrito e eu discordo da sua resposta já que ela fala que a construção da linguagem dá mais performance por ter complexidade mais interessante, porém qualquer função pode ter a mesma complexidade, se o motivo fosse esse não faria sentido ser uma construção de linguagem, o que é bom porque sua resposta reforçou a minha que diz que é algo desnecessário e só foi feito porque o *design* da linguagem é uma gambiarra. Embora seja verdade sobre a complexidade (acho porque não fui a fundo), ela é irrelevante para a pergunta que é sobre o *design* da linguagem. Mesmo discordando não a negativei.

Comment: @Maniero no resumo disso tudo, apesar de discordarmos um do outro o bom é que terá pelo menos dois pontos de vistas diferentes para agregar valor a pergunta. Vou até reler, pois não lembro de ter escrito que a construção da mais performance, ela serve para validar a sintaxe. A performance está condicionada a complexidade do algoritmo.

Answer (score 2):

> O que seria um construtor da linguagem em PHP? Quais são eles?

O construtor da linguagem ou palavas reservadas são as gramáticas definidas /usadas pelo analisador léxico para interpretar uma sintaxe. Programas como lex/flex e yacc/bison que compõe esse universo de analise léxica. Por exemplo: Se você quiser escrever uma nova linguagem você terá que definir quais os comandos ela aceita ou não, em qual ordem dever ser escrito e definir cada detalhe para que o computador saiba interpretar os comandos e inclusive saber o que fazer quando algo estiver escrito na sua nova linguagem.

Suponhamos que você tenha definido entre outros as palavras ("procurar" e "negativar"), essas palavras serão reservadas.  o lex/flex em conjunto yacc/bison trabalham para ler essas entradas e gerar um código em C já otimizado para reconhecer a sua sintaxe e trata-la conforme você definiu. O commando "isset" do php também é definido na gramatica da linguagem, mais especificamente em no arquivo [zend_language_scanner.l](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.1.22/Zend/zend_language_scanner.l) o código fonte está disponível se desejar ter mais informações. Já a função "array_key_exists" ela não está presente do construtor léxico. Ela não é uma palavra reservada por não fazer da sintaxe (idioma) php, porém ela existe e agrega funcionalidades ao core do php e compõe o módulo standard do php , "array_key_exists" você pode achar mais informações no "[php_array.h](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.1.22/ext/standard/php_array.h)" e "[array.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.1.22/ext/standard/array.c)", como pode ser observado ao contrário do isset que é definda na construção da sintaxe, ela não é definida na criação da linguagem, mas sim "adicionada" "PHP_FUNCTION(array_key_exists)", [assim como você pode poderia estar criando um módulo próprio e adicionando qualquer outra função](https://imasters.com.br/back-end/como-criar-uma-extensao-php-c-para-manipular-arrays-parte-01-extensao-basica-de-uma-classe-array).

Você pode encontrar alguns token usados no php [direto no manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) ou ainda no [código fonte](https://github.com/php/php-src). [Se desejar, pode também encontrar no próprio stackoverflow um post sobre análise léxica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113578/o-que-%C3%A9-analise-l%C3%A9xica) também tem muito material interessante sobre isso na internet.

*Observação:*

*lex, flex, yacc e bison são programas diferentes. E inseridos no contexto apenas para facilitar, caso deseje obter mais referências sobre o assunto*

> Por que a documentação do PHP recomenda, em alguns casos, usar construtores da linguagem ao invés das funções?

No caso do isset e array_key_exists a recomendação que encontrei no site é devido à questões de performance, conforme na própria página da documentação do php, uma das sugestões não é de substituir, mas de usar ambos. Existe um Benchmark, mostrando o tempo de execução do algoritmos.

O motivo de um ser mais rápida do que a outra, não é exclusivamente o fato de uma ser um construtor de linguagem e outra ser uma função, mas também a complexidade do algoritmos para executar um isset ou um array_key_exists.

A complexidade do algoritmo pode fazer com que você ganhe ou perca desempenho dependendo do volume do uso. Como cada caso é um caso, o ideal é ler tanto a documentação quanto a nota para obter mais informação, e caso ainda reste dúvida, tenha necessidade e/ou interesse é possível ter acesso ao código fonte.

No isset e array_key_exists o que foi apontado foi o desempenho, porém podem ser questões desde de depreciação, retro compatibilidade e etc...,mas volto a dizer, cada caso é um caso.

> A título de curiosidade essa é a implementação do array_key_exists no
>   php 7.1

```
PHP_FUNCTION(array_key_exists)
{
    zval *key;                  /* key to check for */
    HashTable *array;           /* array to check in */

    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_START(2, 2)
        Z_PARAM_ZVAL(key)
        Z_PARAM_ARRAY_OR_OBJECT_HT(array)
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_END();

    switch (Z_TYPE_P(key)) {
        case IS_STRING:
            if (zend_symtable_exists_ind(array, Z_STR_P(key))) {
                RETURN_TRUE;
            }
            RETURN_FALSE;
        case IS_LONG:
            if (zend_hash_index_exists(array, Z_LVAL_P(key))) {
                RETURN_TRUE;
            }
            RETURN_FALSE;
        case IS_NULL:
            if (zend_hash_exists_ind(array, ZSTR_EMPTY_ALLOC())) {
                RETURN_TRUE;
            }
            RETURN_FALSE;

        default:
            php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "The first argument should be either a string or an integer");
            RETURN_FALSE;
    }
}
```

> Nos casos em que os construtores da linguagem se assemelham às funções (como isset, empty e require), quais são as principais diferenças entre os Construtores da linguagem e as funções?

Os "Construtores da linguagem" como citado anteriormente seriam a gramática da linguagem "consultar análisador léxico". Já as funções "nesse caso" seriam outros recursos (funções) definidas em módulos e extensões do php.

Espero que isso te ajuda de alguma forma.