# Tipo de dados numéricos com caracteres no Access

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, tipagem, microsoft-access

Eu tenho um banco no Ae eu tenho vários campos que são essencialmente numéricos. Só que os números podem conter o sinal de < ou >. Esses campos podem ser usados para cálculos por isso não queria colocar o tipo como texto. O sinal de > e < são relevantes eu não posso simplesmente removê-los porque de acordo com o que a pessoa está trabalhando ela pode escolher trabalhar com o limite ou qualquer outra regra.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Se podem ser usados para cálculos não pode conter esses sinais. Se podem conter esses sinais não podem ser usados para cálculos. Então sue problema é outro, você precisa interpretar o que foi digitado, isso chama-se [*parsing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113578/101), e trabalhar a informação de um jeito apropriado, então separa o que é número de fato e armazena assim e armazena o texto também para atender este requisito (que eu acho que está mal pensado, mas isto é outra estória). Então seu problema é definir bem estas regras ortográficas e gramaticais do texto que pode ser entrado para separar o que é só número e usar isto para cálculos.

Se isto for muito complicado para realizar então tem que pedir para a pessoa entrar com o texto e o número isolado em seguida para armazenar separado.

Esse dado em si claramente é para usar um texto comum (`Text` ou `Memo`), e a parte que deve ser número como `Integer` ou `Double` ou `Currency`. É provável que outros elementos precisem precisem ser gravados em isolado para dar semântica ao valor e quem sabe até tomar algumas decisões. Não existe um tipo de dado milagroso que entenda tudo do jeito que a pessoa desejar adivinhando as regras daquele texto, para isso existe um profissional programando as regras.