# Como passar uma string para dois tipos inteiros?

Tags: java

Eu estou fazendo um exercício onde o programa recebe como entrada uma "String" com dois valores , e no final eu preciso colocar esses dois valores em variáveis inteiras e realizar a soma deles.
Pesquisei e li sobre o BufferReader e o StringTokenizer.
A minha dúvida é como implementar isso, eu preciso fazer um BufferReader para ler a String que vai ser inserida e a StringTokenizer realiza essa separação da minha string em dois? E como eu transformo essa string em inteiros?

```
Entrada: "11 8"
Saida : 19
```

Código que fiz até agora:

```
public class MinhaPrimeiraClasse {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String valor = " ";
    
    System.out.println("Insira os valores:");
    valor = br.nextLine();
    Integer a = 0;
    Integer b = 0;
    Integer c = a + b;
    
    a = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    b = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    System.out.println(" "+c);

 }
}
```

Não sei como fazer a separação da string e jogar os dois valores nas variáveis `a` e `b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi por que você está somando `a` com `b` antes mesmo de atribuir os valores digitados pelo usuário à essas variáveis, mas para separar uma string basta utilizar o método `split` passando o separador como parâmetro.

Então você faria

```
System.out.println("Insira os valores: ");
String entrada = br.nextLine();
String[] valores = entrada.split(" ");

int a = Integer.parseInt(valores[0]);
int b = Integer.parseInt(valores[1]);
int c = a + b;
```

Isso considerando que o usuário não irá entrar com um valor inválido.

Comment: Realmente eu acabei não vendo esse erro na linha da soma, mas deu certo, só troquei o br.nextLine() por br.readLine(); Dúvida resolvida, podem fechar o tópico

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar a classe [`java.util.Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) que é um [scanner de texto simples](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113578/o-que-%C3%A9-analise-l%C3%A9xica) que pode analisar e strings e tipos primitivos usando expressões regulares. A instancia de `Scanner` divide sua entrada em [tokens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Token) usando um delimitador, que por padrão corresponde a espaços em branco. Os tokens resultantes podem então ser convertidos em valores de diferentes tipos.

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
  //Método para leitura de um inteiro de um Scanner.
  private static int lerInteiro(Scanner sc) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    //Verifica se o próximo token a ser lido é um inteiro.
    if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
      return sc.nextInt();                       //Se for o próximo token um inteiro o retorna.
    }
    //Se próximo token não for um inteiro atira uma exceção. 
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(sc.next() + " valor inválido."); 
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a, b;                                    //Declara 'a' e 'b'.
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);         //Inicializa uma instancia de Scanner em System.in.
    System.out.println("Insira os valores:");
    //Abre um bloco de tratamento de exceções.
    try {
      a = lerInteiro(sc);                         //Lê um inteiro em 'a'.
      b = lerInteiro(sc);                         //Lê um inteiro em 'b'.
      System.out.println(a + b);                  //Imprime a soma de 'a' e 'b'.
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());         //Caso haja uma exceção de leitura de um dos valores imprime a mensagem de erro.
    }
  }
}
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/SumInts#Main.java)</sup>

O método [`Scanner.hasNextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) retorna verdadeiro se o próximo token na entrada pode ser interpretado como um valor `int`.
O método [`Scanner.nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) retorna próximo token da entrada como um `int`.
O método [`Scanner.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) retorna próximo token da entrada como uma `string`.
O método [`Scanner.close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#close()) fecha a instancia de `Scanner`. *Antes de usar `Scanner.close()` veja as orientações em [Erro de compilação: “Resource leak” ao usar Scanner](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/380095/erro-de-compila%C3%A7%C3%A3o-resource-leak-ao-usar-scanner/380458#380458).*

Leia também [Java Tutorial Exceções](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html).

Comment: No caso específico do `System.in`, não precisa (e até diria que não se deve) fechá-lo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/380458/112052

Comment: @hkotsubo. Eu não sabia disso, para mim tinha que fechar em todos os casos.

Answer (score 0):

Bom de forma simples o que eu entendi é que voce precisa receber dois valores que virao de forma de String converter eles em Integer e somar eles.

Voce pode fazer o seguinte

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer valor1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        Integer valor2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        System.out.println("valor1: " + valor1);
        System.out.println("valor2: " + valor2);
        System.out.println("Soma dos Valores: " + (valor1 + valor2));
    }
```

o args é chamado na execucao do programa Java, ele é um Array de String, dessa forma seria apenas necessario a conversao dos seus itens que ao String para um Integer dessa forma por exemplo

```
Integer valor1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

e quando for executar o programa voce passaria os valores
por exemplo

```
java Programa.class valor1 valor2
```