# O que é compilador?

Tags: compilação

O que é compilador? Poderiam exemplificar? E qual é a diferença entre compilador e gramática?

Comment: Acho que essas duas perguntas respondem: [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/91) e [Como é feito um compilador?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/91)

Comment: Editei a pergunta. O título que estava antes não retrata o conteúdo da mesma.

Answer (score 4):

Um compilador é um programa que recebe código-fonte, escrito em uma linguagem de programação, e retorna um programa em outra linguagem, geralmente um executável, em linguagem de máquina, para ser executado depois.

Uma gramática é o conjunto de regras de sintaxe usado para validar o código-fonte de uma determinada linguagem de programação; cada linguagem tem sua gramática.

Uma das tarefas do compilador é verificar se o código-fonte passado para ele atende às regras de sintaxe da linguagem. Caso o código-fonte tenha erros de sintaxe, o compilador avisa com mensagens de erro.

Para algumas linguagens, em vez de um compilador, há um interpretador: tem a mesma função de um compilador (gerar código de máquina), mas gera o código de máquina e o executa na hora, sem gravar um executável. JavaScript, por exemplo, é uma linguagem interpretada. Várias linguagens, como Java, PHP e C#, adotam uma abordagem híbrida, compilando o código-fonte para uma linguagem intermediária, mais simples, e interpretando o programa nessa linguagem.

Mais informação na Wikipedia (em inglês):

- [Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler)
- [Interpreted language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language)
- [Formal grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar)
- [Extended Backus–Naur Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form)

Answer (score 0):

Compilador é uma software que pega um arquivo fonte e analisa a sintase do código-fonte. Caso o código-fonte esteja certo ele transformará o código fonte em linguagem de máquina (ou uma linguagem intermediaria que será interpretada, como no caso do Java). Caso tenha algum problema o compilador avisa sobre o problema encontrado no código-fonte