# O que é Bootstrapping?

Tags: terminologia

Não entendi direito o que seria esse *bootstrapping*. Vi alguma coisa que ser uma forma de inicializar uma aplicação.

Não estou falando do Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, e me perdoe se pareci grosso.

Comment: Agora dá pra ver que a dúvida tem a ver com a multiplicidade de sentidos, melhorou bastante. Vale dizer que isso rendeu longas discussões no site Meta, para justamente determinar o uso da tag bootstrap

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4718/qual-deve-ser-o-uso-correto-da-tag-bootstrap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Bootstrapping* é ação de iniciar algo por conta própria. Mesmo esse termo em programação tem pelo menos dois contextos.

Quando algo inicia e prepara o ambiente para o que importa rodar é um processo de *boot*. O mais comum é um sistema operacional que carrega um software básico para depois carregar o resto do sistema operacional que é o que importa. Iso pode ocorrer com outros tipos de softwares, especialmente plataformas, como web (Electron), ou VMs como .NET ou JVM, só para citar alguns.

Pode ser você fazer algo com uma tecnologia existente para criar uma nova tecnologia e depois mudar para a tecnologia criada, provavelmente para dar continuidade com ela própria.

Pense no problema do ovo e da galinha, quem nasceu primeiro?

Falo disso como exemplo em [Como é feito um compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101).

Para ter uma ideia da quantidade de significados basta visitar a [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping). Destaco o uso em estatística e áreas derivadas usadas na computação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).