# Como implementações alternativas de linguagens funcionam, como Python na JVM?

Tags: terminologia, compiladores, interpretador

Sempre vejo pessoas falando sobre implementações de linguagens X em uma outra linguagem Y. Como por exemplo:

- [JRuby](https://www.jruby.org/), uma implementação do Ruby em Java
- [Jython](https://www.jython.org/), uma implementação do Python em Java
- [IronPython](https://ironpython.net/), uma implementação do Python em .NET
- [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino), uma implementação do JavaScript em Java

Como isso funciona? Que vantagens são ganhas ao "implementar" uma linguagem em outra? É realmente uma implementação em outra linguagem, ou só em uma outra plataforma, compilador ou coisa assim? Qual é o nome dessa técnica?

Comment: Toda linguagem é implementada em outra linguagem

Comment: @LINQ todo byte é esfregado para gerar mais bytes :D

Comment: Pera lá, você fez a pergunta propositalmente pra dar essa Big-resposta que você já sabia sobre o assunto? XD Porque independente disso, sua resposta foi ótima =D

Answer (score 5):

## O que é uma linguagem de programação, afinal?

Para entender todo esse assunto, é preciso entender o conceito de linguagem de programação. Seja BASIC, FORTRAN, Java, Ruby, C# ou Crystal, uma linguagem de programação é uma **notação** para expressar um algorítimo.

É como uma língua falada, cada uma tem suas especificidades, porém todas dividem uma característica: comunicação. Pode-se mudar a gramática, o alfabeto, a origem, a ferramenta usada para falar (como por exemplo a voz ou as próprias mãos), mas mantem-se a comunicação como objetivo.

Veja que uma linguagem de programação é somente a notação, e não a execução. E é por isso que **não** existem linguagens compiladas e linguagens interpretadas. O que existe são implementações de linguagens de forma compilada e outras interpretadas.

## Tá, mas o que é a implementação da linguagem?

Toda essa confusão é porque toda linguagem de programação vem com uma implementação (ou pelo menos deveria, para ser útil). Quando falamos: "eu rodo Ruby em minha máquina", na verdade, provavelmente, queremos dizer: "eu escrevo código Ruby, porém rodo CRuby em minha máquina".

A implementação padrão do Ruby é o [CRuby/MRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_MRI), que é um interpretador. Essa implementação padrão é chamada de [*reference implementation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_implementation). A mesma coisa acontence em Python, que na verdade, tem sua *reference implementation* chamada [CPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython) (não confunda com Cython).

Isso fica um pouco mais claro de se ver no mundo Java. O nome de uma das versões da linguagem é Java SE 12, e sua *reference implementation* é o OpenJDK 12. Existem outras implementações da linguagem Java SE 12, como o [GNU Compiler for Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_for_Java).

E mais claro ainda no JavaScript. Aliás, o que é JavaScript? Não passa de um [monte de documentos de texto](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262) que definem sua especificação. A partir dessa especificação, são escritas *engines* como o [V8 do Chrome](https://v8.dev/) e o [SpiderMonkey do Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey).

Como o [@LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/18246/linq) mencionou nos comentários, toda linguagem é implementada em outra linguagem. Gostaria de adicionar que toda linguagem é implementada em um (outro) sistema de execução. Seja um compilador ou interpretador. Seja GCC ou a JVM.

## E qual é a vantagem dessas implementações alternativas?

Aí varia de *reference implementation* pra *reference implementation*. O CRuby e o CPython, por exemplo, não têm suporte a concorrência de verdade. Eles tem suporte a código multi-thread, mas essas threads não rodam ao mesmo tempo, por conta do GIL (Global Interpreter Lock). Ao implementar essas linguagens na JVM, como Jython e JRuby, você pode obter concorrência de verdade, mantendo a notação da linguagem.

Se você precisa, por algum motivo, interoperar código Python e Java, talvez valha a pena utilizar uma implementação de Python na JVM, já que executaria código Java de forma nativa.

Também dá pra fazer umas coisas que ainda me quebram a cabeça só de pensar:

[image]

E pra quebrar mais ainda a cabeça, rodei esse script escrito em Ruby, rodando em JRuby, compilado ou interpretado na JVM, no Ubuntu com o kernel do Windows (WSL).

## E como tudo isso funciona?

É uma baita reescrita. No caso do JRuby, todo o código que antes era C, foi portado para Java. O CRuby também tem código Ruby, e no caso, esse código pode ser preservado, já que vai agora chamar dependências Java. É por isso que gems escritas e testadas em CRuby tem grandes chances de serem 100% compatíveis com JRuby.

E como disse, é reescrita (ou melhor, reimplementação). Aqui está o [método `String#upcase!` em JRuby](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/8748733b53a7f36d5021c91b07fd23c4d7a6e82a/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyString.java#L1845):

```
private IRubyObject upcase_bang(ThreadContext context, int flags) {
    modifyAndKeepCodeRange();
    Encoding enc = checkDummyEncoding();
    if (((flags & Config.CASE_ASCII_ONLY) != 0 && (enc.isUTF8() || enc.maxLength() == 1)) ||
            (flags & Config.CASE_FOLD_TURKISH_AZERI) == 0 && getCodeRange() == CR_7BIT) {
        int s = value.getBegin();
        int end = s + value.getRealSize();
        byte[]bytes = value.getUnsafeBytes();
        while (s < end) {
            int c = bytes[s] & 0xff;
            if (Encoding.isAscii(c) && 'a' <= c && c <= 'z') {
                bytes[s] = (byte)('A' + (c - 'a'));
                flags |= Config.CASE_MODIFIED;
            }
            s++;
        }
    } else {
        flags = caseMap(context.runtime, flags, enc);
        if ((flags & Config.CASE_MODIFIED) != 0) clearCodeRange();
    }

    return ((flags & Config.CASE_MODIFIED) != 0) ? this : context.nil;
}
```

E já no [CRuby](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-upcase):

```
rb_str_upcase_bang(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE str)
{
    rb_encoding *enc;
    OnigCaseFoldType flags = ONIGENC_CASE_UPCASE;

    flags = check_case_options(argc, argv, flags);
    str_modify_keep_cr(str);
    enc = STR_ENC_GET(str);
    rb_str_check_dummy_enc(enc);
    if (((flags&ONIGENC_CASE_ASCII_ONLY) && (enc==rb_utf8_encoding() || rb_enc_mbmaxlen(enc)==1))
        || (!(flags&ONIGENC_CASE_FOLD_TURKISH_AZERI) && ENC_CODERANGE(str)==ENC_CODERANGE_7BIT)) {
        char *s = RSTRING_PTR(str), *send = RSTRING_END(str);

        while (s < send) {
            unsigned int c = *(unsigned char*)s;

            if (rb_enc_isascii(c, enc) && 'a' <= c && c <= 'z') {
                *s = 'A' + (c - 'a');
                flags |= ONIGENC_CASE_MODIFIED;
            }
            s++;
        }
    }
    else if (flags&ONIGENC_CASE_ASCII_ONLY)
        rb_str_ascii_casemap(str, &flags, enc);
    else
        str_shared_replace(str, rb_str_casemap(str, &flags, enc));

    if (ONIGENC_CASE_MODIFIED&flags) return str;
    return Qnil;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Essencialmente tudo isto já foi respondido em outras perguntas, e algumas coisas na resposta estão um pouco mal definidas. Então sugiro antes de mais nada ler as seguintes perguntas/respostas:

- [Especificação e Implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101)
- [Como é desenvolvida uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124436/101)
- [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101)
- [A primeira linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156521/101)
- [O que caracteriza uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre linguagem compilada para linguagem interpretada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77070/101)
- [Como é feito um compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101)
- [Afinal, Java é uma plataforma ou uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/266489/101)
- [Seria preciso ter outra linguagem de programação para se criar o assembler?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/206435/101)
- [O que é Bootstrapping?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/328007/101)

> Como isso funciona?

Isto é um pouco amplo para responder com detalhes, mas não tem nada muito especial e acredito que os *links* acima respondem bem tudo isto. Além do que "como funciona" é um pouco vago, na verdade a pergunta como um todo está.

> Que vantagens são ganhas ao "implementar" uma linguagem em outra?

Me parece que não era isto que queria perguntar aqui. Vide resposta abaixo.

A maior vantagem é rodar naquela plataforma se o objetivo era rodar em uma plataforma diferente. E possivelmente poder ter interoperabilidade dentro desta plataforma.

Se for uma implementação na mesma plataforma pode ser o segundo grande motivo que é a implementação fazer de forma melhor alguma coisa que as implementações anteriores não conseguiam ou não faziam bem, por exemplo podia não ter performance, não ter acesso a determinadas APIs, ou só ter uma certa interoperabilidade.

Embora o exemplo citado na resposta seja plausível geralmente isto nem é algo fundamental porque a linguagem não foi feita pensando nisso e não poderá usar da melhor forma possível, a não ser que ela vire um dialeto. E de fato é comum este tipo de coisa virar dialeto e o código escrito em uma plataforma não rodar em outra implementação.

Está apenas fazendo outra implementação. Algumas implementações alternativas podem ter vantagens, outras não, depende do que se fez.

> É realmente uma implementação em outra linguagem, ou só em uma outra plataforma, compilador ou coisa assim?

Pelo que entendi está perguntando sobre implementar em outra plataforma. E está usando um compilador diferente. Curiosamente em alguns casos nem precisaria de um compilador diferente, apenas trocar *backend* dele, ou seja, o gerador, mas por alguma razão preferiram trocar tudo, tem alguns motivos para fazer isto.

> Qual é o nome dessa técnica?

Está confuso sobre que técnica está falando, se for usar uma linguagem para escrever o compilador e talvez outras partes do que compõe a linguagem chama-se *bootstrapping*, também já respondido. Se for criar uma implementação alternativa não tem termo específico, costumamos falar que está **portando a implementação** quando realmente pega-se uma implementação e muda para outra plataforma ou só estamos fazendo uma implementação alternativa sem nem estar portando, apenas estamos concretizando uma especificação do zero.

A resposta fala em reescrita, mas isto pode não ser o melhor termo. Pode ser, mas pode ser só uma nova escrita, e em alguns casos nem ter a reescrita, apenas uma leve adaptação, seja no compilador, seja na biblioteca padrão que parece ser o que postou na resposta.

Answer (score 0):

No site da Rhino ela diz o seguinte:

> Rhino is an open-source implementation of JavaScript written entirely in Java. It is typically embedded into Java applications to provide scripting to end users. It is embedded in J2SE 6 as the default Java scripting engine.

Nesse caso a implementação tem como objetivo prover uma forma de scripting em Javascript para programas em Java. É uma forma de estender a linguagem hospedeira nesse caso.