# como fazer um interpretador em nodejs interpretar recursão de uma função

Tags: javascript, node.js, loop, compilação, interpretador

## Contexto

Estou participando da rinha de compiladores, e quero fazer um interpretador, escolhi JS pois estou aprendendo e focando meus estudos em uma única linguagem, enfim o interpretador funciona lendo uma árvore sintática abstrata por meio de um json, preciso fazer uma função fib ("Fibonacci") funcionar, não estou conseguindo identificar o erro, vou colocar a arvore, o código da linguagem e o código do interpretador aqui.

### Código Na Linguagem:

```
let fib = fn (n) => {
  if (n < 2) {
    n
  } else {
    fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
  }
};
print("fib: " + fib(10))
```

### AST:

```
{
    "name": "source.rinha",
    "expression": {
        "kind": "Let",
        "name": {
            "text": "fib",
            "location": {
                "start": 4,
                "end": 7,
                "filename": "source.rinha"
            }
        },
        "value": {
            "kind": "Function",
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "text": "n",
                    "location": {
                        "start": 14,
                        "end": 15,
                        "filename": "source.rinha"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "value": {
                "kind": "If",
                "condition": {
                    "kind": "Binary",
                    "lhs": {
                        "kind": "Var",
                        "text": "n",
                        "location": {
                            "start": 29,
                            "end": 30,
                            "filename": "source.rinha"
                        }
                    },
                    "op": "Lt",
                    "rhs": {
                        "kind": "Int",
                        "value": 2,
                        "location": {
                            "start": 33,
                            "end": 34,
                            "filename": "source.rinha"
                        }
                    },
                    "location": {
                        "start": 29,
                        "end": 34,
                        "filename": "source.rinha"
                    }
                },
                "then": {
                    "kind": "Var",
                    "text": "n",
                    "location": {
                        "start": 43,
                        "end": 44,
                        "filename": "source.rinha"
                    }
                },
                "otherwise": {
                    "kind": "Binary",
                    "lhs": {
                        "kind": "Call",
                        "callee": {
                            "kind": "Var",
                            "text": "fib",
                            "location": {
                                "start": 62,
                                "end": 65,
                                "filename": "source.rinha"
                            }
                        },
                        "arguments": [
                            {
                                "kind": "Binary",
                                "lhs": {
                                    "kind": "Var",
                                    "text": "n",
                                    "location": {
                                        "start": 66,
                                        "end": 67,
                                        "filename": "source.rinha"
                                    }
                                },
                                "op": "Sub",
                                "rhs": {
                                    "kind": "Int",
                                    "value": 1,
                                    "location": {
                                        "start": 68,
                                        "end": 69,
                                        "filename": "source.rinha"
                                    }
                                },
                                "location": {
                                    "start": 66,
                                    "end": 69,
                                    "filename": "source.rinha"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "location": {
                            "start": 62,
                            "end": 70,
                            "filename": "source.rinha"
                        }
                    },
                    "op": "Add",
                    "rhs": {
                        "kind": "Call",
                        "callee": {
                            "kind": "Var",
                            "text": "fib",
                            "location": {
                                "start": 73,
                                "end": 76,
                                "filename": "source.rinha"
                            }
                        },
                        "arguments": [
                            {
                                "kind": "Binary",
                                "lhs": {
                                    "kind": "Var",
                                    "text": "n",
                                    "location": {
                                        "start": 77,
                                        "end": 78,
                                        "filename": "source.rinha"
                                    }
                                },
                                "op": "Sub",
                                "rhs": {
                                    "kind": "Int",
                                    "value": 2,
                                    "location": {
                                        "start": 79,
                                        "end": 80,
                                        "filename": "source.rinha"
                                    }
                                },
                                "location": {
                                    "start": 77,
                                    "end": 80,
                                    "filename": "source.rinha"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "location": {
                            "start": 73,
                            "end": 81,
                            "filename": "source.rinha"
                        }
                    },
                    "location": {
                        "start": 62,
                        "end": 81,
                        "filename": "source.rinha"
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "start": 25,
                    "end": 86,
                    "filename": "source.rinha"
                }
            },
            "location": {
                "start": 10,
                "end": 89,
                "filename": "source.rinha"
            }
        },
        "next": {
            "kind": "Print",
            "value": {
                "kind": "Binary",
                "lhs": {
                    "kind": "Str",
                    "value": "fib: ",
                    "location": {
                        "start": 98,
                        "end": 105,
                        "filename": "source.rinha"
                    }
                },
                "op": "Add",
                "rhs": {
                    "kind": "Call",
                    "callee": {
                        "kind": "Var",
                        "text": "fib",
                        "location": {
                            "start": 108,
                            "end": 111,
                            "filename": "source.rinha"
                        }
                    },
                    "arguments": [
                        {
                            "kind": "Int",
                            "value": 10,
                            "location": {
                                "start": 112,
                                "end": 114,
                                "filename": "source.rinha"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "location": {
                        "start": 108,
                        "end": 115,
                        "filename": "source.rinha"
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "start": 98,
                    "end": 115,
                    "filename": "source.rinha"
                }
            },
            "location": {
                "start": 92,
                "end": 116,
                "filename": "source.rinha"
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "start": 0,
            "end": 116,
            "filename": "source.rinha"
        }
    },
    "location": {
        "start": 0,
        "end": 116,
        "filename": "source.rinha"
    }
}
```

### Código do interpretador:

```
function operators(node){
    const lhs = interpret(node.lhs);
    const rhs = interpret(node.rhs);
    console.log(lhs+node.op+rhs);
    switch (node.op) {
        case "Add":
            return lhs+rhs;
        case "Sub":
            return lhs-rhs;
        case "Mul":
            return lhs*rhs;
        case "Div":
            return lhs/rhs;
        case "Rem":
            return lhs%rhs;
        case "Lt":
            return lhs<rhs;
        case "Gt":
            return lhs>rhs;
        case "Lte":
            return lhs<=rhs;
        case "Gte":
            return lhs>=rhs;
        case "And":
            return lhs&&rhs;
        case "Or":
            return lhs||rhs;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

const environment = {};

function interpret(node) {
    switch (node.kind) {
        case "Print":
            console.log(interpret(node.value));
            break;

        case "Let":
            environment[node.name.text] = interpret(node.value);
            return interpret(node.next);
        
        case "Function":
            return function (...arg){
                for(let i = 0; i<node.parameters.length; i++){
                    environment[node.parameters[i].text] = arg[i];
                }
                return interpret(node.value);
            }
        case "If":
            const value = interpret(node.condition);
            if(value){
                return interpret(node.then);
            }
            else{
                return interpret(node.otherwise);
            }
        case "Call":
            const callee = interpret(node.callee);
            const arg = node.arguments.map((arg) => interpret(arg));
            return callee(...arg);
        case "Var":
            return environment[node.text];

        case "Tuple":
            return "("+interpret(node.first)+","+interpret(node.second)+")";
        
        case "First":
            return interpret(node.value.first);

        case "Second":
            return interpret(node.value.second);
        
        case "Binary":
            return operators(node);

        default:
            return node.value;
    }
}

module.exports = interpret;
```

Comment: Você está acoplando análise e execução dos nós da AST? É tenso fazer assim, em momentos ficarão indistinguíveis o que é fase análise e fase de execução. Na análise da AST você vai montando o código para ser executado após concluir a fase de analise, é mais suave.

Comment: Só consegui pensar nessa forma, eu transformo o código em uma AST por meio de um programinha em rust que eles me fornecem, tenho que interpretar essa AST, não sei como dividir a análise e execução desta forma.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como é feito um compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104814/como-%c3%a9-feito-um-compilador)